# Is it possible to run a SQLPLUS script on a file encoded as UTF-8 with BOM

Tags: oracle, utf-8, plsql, byte-order-mark

I'm trying to run a collection of scripts which have been auto-generated from a large number of sources.  Unfortunately some of these have been generated as UTF-8 with BOM.  I have in place a system for automatically removing the BOM, but its a bit of a messy process.

Failing to remove the BOM generates the error:

```
SP2-0042: unknown command "ï»¿" - rest of line ignored.
```

Is it possible to run SQLPLUS on a script file which has a BOM?

Comment: No idea, but I'd start by looking into the client side character set setting to see if it was different than UTF-8. Actually, if automated, I would leave in place the process to strip the BOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to run SQLPLUS with such script, but SQLPLUS will indicate an error on the first line because of [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).
Probably you wanted to ask if you can avoid this error - **it is not possible**, AFAIK. [Erwin](http://toadfororacle.com/thread.jspa?threadID=28951) thinks so too.

You can workaround losing any information by generating those files with an empty first line. Then you can just ignore this error.

Comment: Sadly the SQL script is being used as part of a KSH script.  The error output from SQLPlus trips up the KSH script.  Thanks for the response though. It confirms that BOM stripping was necessary.

Answer (score 6):

This has been a bug open with Oracle for over 6 years now, but it doesn't look like they are interested in fixing it.

Their 'recommended workaround' ([Doc ID 788156.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=788156.1#aref_section341) Section C.6) is to strip the BOM or make your first script line a comment, and then ignore this error.

> SP2-0042: unknown command "∩╗┐" - rest of line ignored.

Or

> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "-- Commen..." - rest of line
>   ignored.

[Bug 13515585 Details](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?id=13515585) (requires OTN login):

```
Bug 13515585: ADD SUPPORT FOR THE UTF-8 BOM IN SQLPLUS
Bug Status: Internal (Oracle) Review 
Created: 19-Dec-2011 
Updated: 29-Sep-2015
```