# SQL*Plus - Spool CSV - SP2-0734: unknown command beginnin

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

When I launch the following task .cmd :

```
sqlplus -s User/Password@database @Query.sql 'G:'
```

I get this error :

```
SP2-0734: unknown command beginnin
```

Even adding set `sqlblanklines on` it failed.

With a simple query like `select * from table1` it works.

With a more complex query ( multiple join, group by) it does not work => Even if the file is well generated. Inside the file, I  just find errors details.

Please find below more details about the issue :

```
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "FROM NOTI...." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "INNER JOIN..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "INNER JOIN..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "INNER JOIN..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "INNER JOIN..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "INNER JOIN..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "INNER JOIN..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "INNER JOIN..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "LEFT JOIN ..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "LEFT join ..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "LEFT join ..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "LEFT JOIN ..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "LEFT join ..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "LEFT join ..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "WHERE NOTI..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "GROUP BY N..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning ",table1..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning ",table2..." - rest of line ignored.
```

Comment: You claim that the file is "well generated".  SQL*Plus and/or Oracle are indicating that there are syntax errors.  I would tend to trust Oracle.  The fact that it only fails when you try to generate a more complex script only makes it more likely that the problem is that your script has errors.  Since you're not showing us the script, there isn't much we can suggest.

Comment: Might help to show your Query.sql file, since that has the code that is erroring. And format all the error messages properly. Why have you mentioned Toad in the title? Spooling and CSV don't seem to be relevant either, even if you are doing that in the file you haven't shown.

Comment: Hello @AlexPoole and JustinCave Thanks for your reply. Sorry, you are right, I just edit my post with the SQL script. Have you a idea of the issue ? Indeed dor this script I do not use toad, only SQL*Plus.

Comment: Hello AlexPoole and @JustinCave Thanks for your reply. Sorry, you are right, I just edit my post with the SQL script. Have you a idea of the issue ? Indeed dor this script I do not use toad, only SQL*Plus.

Answer (score 6):

By default SQL*Plus treats a blank line [as terminating the previous command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#sthref273):

> A blank line in a SQL statement or script tells SQL*Plus that you have finished entering the command, but do not want to run it yet.

The first blank line, before the `FROM`, terminates the `SELECT` - but it is not executed since the last line does not have a semicolon on the end and you don't have a `/` on the next line. That partial `SELECT` is held in the statement buffer but is never executed.

SQL*Plus then tries to interpret the rest of the file, but as each subsequent line doesn't start with something it recognises as SQL, and isn't a SQL*Plus command, you get SP2-0044 for all of them.

You can either remove the blank lines in the middle of the statement; or issue [`SET SQLBLANKLINES ON`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm) at the start of your script:

> Controls whether SQL*Plus puts blank lines within a SQL command or script. ON interprets blank lines and new lines as part of a SQL command or script. OFF, the default value, does not allow blank lines or new lines in a SQL command or script or script.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue even i tried  SET SQLBLANKLINES ON but no  luck. I finally figured out the issue was with file encoding format. Actually I used to save my sql file using visual studio, which saves the file in utf-8 encoding format.

solution- open sql file in notepad -> save  as ANSI encoding format. it works.

Comment: Yes, but this is a different problem than the one posted in this question, even though the error messages are the same. The encoding issue is caused by the BOM in utf8 files which sqlplus is incompatible with. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758094/is-it-possible-to-run-a-sqlplus-script-on-a-file-encoded-as-utf-8-with-bom

Answer (score 0):

SET SQLBLANKLINES ON did not work in my case where I use a cmd script to run and save sqlplus results as a txt file.

Once I added a blank line between a "PROMPT" comment line and the first line of my select statement, the error went away. Before, my select statement line was immediately below the PROMPT line and would produce the SP2-0734.