# SP2-0734: unknown command beginning select

Tags: sql, database, oracle, powershell, tfs

I have continuous automated application deployment building on Azure DevOps server 2019(ex TFS). Part of deploy is checking the Oracle DB status, before running scripts, the script below works for a year, and ones (probably after latest Azure DevOps server update 2019.1) it stops working with an error:

```
SQL> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning " select..." - rest of line ignored. 
SQL> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning " select..." - rest of line ignored.
```

```
$chekdbsql = 'select status from v$instance;'
$i = 1
$chkdb = ""
while ($chkdb.Contains("OPEN") -ne 'True') { 
    Clear-Variable -Name chkdb
    $chkdb = ($chekdbsql | cmd /c "sqlplus -s user/password@localhost/ora as sysdba")
    if ($chkdb.Contains("OPEN") -eq 'True'){
        break 
        }
    echo "Trying to connect to database. Attempt $i"
    sleep 10
    $i++ } 
write-host "Connected! Database's status is 'open'." -ForegroundColor green
```

If I tried to execute command locally on the machine where the application is built - it's work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space before `select` makes me think it's a character encoding issue. See e.g. [this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/23301), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758094/is-it-possible-to-run-a-sqlplus-script-on-a-file-encoded-%20as-utf-8-with-bom/49019748%20)

```
beginning " select..."
```

I'm not familiar enough with powershell to know what the problem is. I can think of a workaround, but it's a bit of a hack.

```
$chekdbsql = "`nselect status from v`$instance;"
```

This makes sure that whatever garbage characters are getting inserted at the beginning of the string will be on their own line in SQL*Plus. So if you get a SP2-0734, your select command will still run after that. Since it's now a double-quoted string, I escaped the `$`.