# How can I make PowerShell handle [ or ] in file name well?

Tags: powershell, path, glob, literals

I modified PowerShell script from [PowerShell - Batch change files encoding To UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18684793).

```bsh
# Modified version of https://stackoverflow.com/q/18684793

[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 'en-US'

$Encoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($True) # If UTF8Encoding($False), It will be UTF-8 without BOM
$source = "C:\Users\AKULA\Desktop\SRC" # source directory
$destination = "C:\Users\AKULA\Desktop\DST" # destination directory

if (!(Test-Path $destination)) {
    New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
}

# Delete all previously generated file
Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -Include * -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {$_.Delete()}

# Recursively convert all files into UTF-8
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem $source -Force -Recurse -Exclude "desktop.ini") {
    if ($i.PSIsContainer) {
        continue
    }

    $name = $i.Fullname.Replace($source, $destination)

    $content = Get-Content $i.Fullname

    if ($null -ne $content) {
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($name, $content, $Encoding)
    } else {
        Write-Host "No content from: $i"   
    }
}
```

But after using it, I've found that PS cannot handle `[` or `]` well.
I made some test files that has diversity in name/content.

```
Get-Content : An object at the specified path C:\Users\AKULA\Desktop\SRC\FILENAME[[[[[[]]]]]]]].txt does not exist, or
has been filtered by the -Include or -Exclude parameter.
At C:\Users\AKULA\Desktop\Convert_to_UTF-8.ps1:24 char:16
+     $content = Get-Content $i.Fullname
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.String[]:String[]) [Get-Content], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Since I cannot embed images in question, here is link of IMGUR album.
Full image list: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtSBS.jpg

These are what I've tested:

- Test files have different names. Their name contains space, `'`,
  `[]`. Also made up different language(Japanese, Korean).
- These files have same content, encoded with UCS-2 BE BOM(UTF-16 BE) so 
  that I can check if it has re-encoded to UTF-8.

How can I make my script handle `[` or `]` in file name well?

Comment: ``-LiteralPath``

Comment: With `-Path` PowerShell handles square brackets `[]` as [wildcards/ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-6) similar to character classes in a RegularExpression.

Comment: @PetSerAl Do you mean `$content = Get-Content -LiteralPath $i.Fullname`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Indeed, use of the **`-LiteralPath` parameter** is the best solution (in PowerShell (Core) v6+, you can shorten to **`-lp`**):

```
$content = Get-Content -LiteralPath $i.Fullname
```

**`-LiteralPath` ensures that `$i.Fullname` is taken *verbatim* (literally)**; that is, `[` and `]` in the path are interpreted as *themselves* rather than having *special meaning*, as they would have as  a **`-Path`** argument, due to being interpreted as a **[wildcard expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards)** - note that **`-Path` is *positionally implied*** if you only pass a *value* (a string) as the first argument, as you did (`Get-Content $i.FullName`)

Note: This answer analogously **applies to *all* cmdlets that have both `-Path` and 
`-LiteralPath` parameters**, such as [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content), [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file), and [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location).

---

As for **what you tried**:

```
$content = Get-Content $i.Fullname
```

is effectively the same as:

```
$content = Get-Content -Path $i.Fullname
```

That is, **the (first) *positional* argument passed to `Get-Content` is implicitly bound to the

`-Path` parameter**.

The **`-Path` parameter accepts [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards)** to allow matching paths by *patterns*; in addition to support for `*` (any run of characters) and `?` (exactly 1 character), **`[...]` inside a wildcard pattern** denotes a **character set** **or range** (e.g., `[12]` or `[0-9]`).

Therefore an actual path that contains `[...]`, e.g., `foo[10].txt`, is *not* recognized as such, because the `[10]` is interpreted as a character set matching a *single* character that is *either* `1` or `0`; that is `foo[10].txt` would match `foo0.txt` and `foo1.txt`, but not a file literally named `foo[10].txt`.

When (implicitly) using `-Path`, it *is* possible to *escape* `[` and `]` instances that should be interpreted verbatim, namely via the backtick (`` ` ``), but note that this can get tricky to get right when quoting and/or variable references are involved.

**If you know a path to be a literal path, it is best to form a habit of using `-LiteralPath`** (which in PowerShell *Core* you can shorten to `-lp`).

**However, if your path contains *literal* `[` and `]` and you *also* need wildcard matching, you must use `` ` ``-escaping** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57778204/45375).

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two situations where the solution's good advice doesn't hold, unfortunately.

### Selective error handling (PS: only an issue in legacy Windows PowerShell)

`Get-Content -LiteralPath "nobox[]"` gives an error message and exception type as if wildcards are involved:

```
Get-Content : An object at the specified path box[] does not exist, or has been filtered by the -Include or -Exclude parameter.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Content -Path "nobox[]"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.String[]:String[]) [Get-Content], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

whereas without the brackets, we get:

```
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'nobox' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Content -LiteralPath "nobox"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nobox:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Therefore, to silently deal with an optional file, but not bluntly suppress every exception, something like:

```
   try {
        $lines = Get-Content -LiteralPath $path -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {
        $lines = @()
    }
```

chokes on paths with brackets.

### Creating a hard or symbolic link

A minor and a major caveat:

- The `Path` parameter, the name of the new item, "works like the LiteralPath parameter of other cmdlets", says the [documentation of New-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-5.1#parameters) clearly, and that seems true and makes sense. Though I wish we could clarify that by writing `-LiteralPath`.
- The `Value` parameter, the target of the link (also known as `Target` secretly in v5 and openly later), does not accept wildcard characters according to the same documentation, but that's a lie. The command:

```
New-Item -ItemType "HardLink" -Path "whatever" -Target "*"
```

makes Powershell squeal "Cannot set the location because path '*' resolved to multiple containers.".

So you always need the escapes for the target. If you have a file named "f[]", then this will display an error:

```
New-Item -ItemType "HardLink" -Path "whatever" -Target "f[]"
```

and this will create a link:

```
New-Item -ItemType "HardLink" -Path "f[2]" -Target ([WildcardPattern]::Escape("f[]"))
```

Same for ItemType "SymbolicLink".

Comment: Good points. There is _some_ progress in these matters: In the modern, cross-platform [PowerShell (Core) edition](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) that succeeds the legacy, Windows-only _Windows PowerShell_ (whose latest and final version is 5.1), (a) the confusing error message you get with `Get-Content -LiteralPath "nosuchfil[]"` has been corrected, and ...

Comment: ... (b) treating `New-Item`'s `-Value` / `-Target` arguments as _literals_ has been _green-lit_ as a (technically breaking, but acceptable) change in [GitHub issue #13136](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13136) - but _yet to be implemented_ as of PowerShell 7.3.2