# Powershell Function String output as input to File based functions

Tags: function, powershell, loops, input, get-childitem

I have Powershell v5 running in Windows 10 64Bit OS.

And I also have a nice trick to make the paths with square brackets compatible to be read by Powershell by escaping with tilde signs like `$Path.Replace('[','`[' ).Replace(']','`]')`, so intuitively I thought, why not make it a function like below for the same:

```
Function GetEscapedPath($Path) {
    Return $Path.Replace('[','`[' ).Replace(']','`]')
}
```

Now I want to use this function return value as input to `Remove-Item` function or any File-fullpath based functions for that matter, but this doesn't work:

```
Remove-Item GetEscapedPath $File.Fullname -WhatIf
```

`$File` is variable from loop on `Get-ChildItem` with `Fullname` selected, but still the above line doesn't print anything.

How can I achieve what I want ?

Comment: I'm not sure the function you've written is required. What happens if you run `Remove-Item $File -WhatIf`?

Comment: Well `Remove-Item` by it's definition needs `Fullpath` of file to be able to remove it, and the `$File` I got from the loop of `Get-ChildItem` is file object in which I can select parameters like `Name`,`Fullname`,`Length` etc. So that's why to convert the fullpath from get-childitem to escaped path, I have written that function

Comment: Ah, now I've tried it, something about square brackets confuses `Remove-Item`. Does `Remove-Item (getEscapedPath $File.Fullname) -WhatIf` work?

Comment: On point, the parenthesis did work, can you format this in answer with some extra info as much as possible ? Thanks a lot btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **`(...)`**, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) **to pass the output from a command or expression as an argument to another command**:

```
# Positionally binds to the -Path parameter, which interprets its argument
# as a wildcard pattern.
Remove-Item (GetEscapedPath $File.Fullname) -WhatIf
```

However, in your particular case, **a function is *not* needed to *escape* a file-system path in order to treat it *literally (verbatim)*: simply use the `-LiteralPath` parameter** of the various file-related cmdlets instead:

```
Remove-Item -LiteralPath $file.FullName -WhatIf
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57777732/45375) for more information.