# Powershell ItemNotFoundException for a file that Powershell itself found

Tags: powershell, path

Can someone explain why this Powershell script doesn't work?  What I see is

- `Set-Location...-$Dir` appears to work as expected
- The current directory is printed as expected
- The filename is printed as expected and I do seem to have entered the expected directory
- `Test-Path` returns `False`!  This despite the `$File` being the one that Powershell itself calculated
- `Set-location...-` throws an `ItemNotFoundException` claiming that the parent path does not exist but it does print the entire parent path correctly in the error.

```
$InformationPreference = 'Continue'

$Dirs = Get-Childitem -Attributes Directory -Path .

foreach ($Dir in $Dirs)
{
    $Files = Get-Childitem -Path $Dir

    foreach ($File in $Files)
    {
        Set-Location -Path $Dir
        Write-Information $pwd
        Write-Information $File
        Test-Path -Path $File
        Set-Location -Path -
    }
}
```

Comment: `Test-Path -Path $File.FullName` and you forgot to enter the path on `Set-Location` (just a hyphen)

Comment: Please copy and paste, as text, the error message into the question.

Comment: Would you consider using `Push-Location` and `Pop-Location`?

Comment: Using `-` as the `-Path` argument in order to return to the previous location only works in [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md). As an aside: `Get-Childitem -Attributes Directory -Path .` can be simplified to `Get-ChildItem -Directory`

Comment: _Windows PowerShell_ situationally stringifies output objects by file _name_ only rather than by _full path_, _depending on how `Get-ChildItem` was invoked_; this problem has been fixed in [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md). The workaround is to use `.FullName` to ensure use of the full path or, if the objects are to be passed to other file-processing cmdlets, to pass them _via the pipeline_. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375) for details.

Comment: @Theo: `-` works as a `-Path` argument in v7+, and means: go back to the previous directory in the location history; `+` navigates forward. Thus, the code in the question is the equivalent of paired `Push-Location` / `Pop-Location` calls.

Comment: Thanks all.  As well as this I realised that the filenames (generated by some MP3 editing software) are also wrong as they look like this: `something [with brackets].mp3` and it appears neither Powershell nor Command like the square-brackets.  Still not managed to make this work but I have at least managed to manually change some filenames.

Comment: As for the problem with `[` and `]`: See the next comment, which summarizes [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57777732/45375).

Comment: The `-Path` (`-FilePath`) parameter of provider (file-handling) cmdlets (which the first _positional_ argument implicitly binds to), expects _wildcard_ expressions. Because PowerShell's wildcard language also supports expressions such as `[a-z]` (to match any English letter), paths meant to be _literal_ ones are misinterpreted if they happen to contain `[` chars. To pass a literal path as such, use the `-LiteralPath` parameter explicitly. Alternatively, pass a file-information object such as produced by `Get-ChildItem` _via the pipeline_ to a provider cmdlet, which also binds to `-LiteralPath`

Comment: I've closed this question as a duplicate of the aforementioned posts, which hopefully in combination solve your problem. If it still isn't solved, I encourage you to create a new question, ideally with a [mcve].