# Decoding base64 with powershell

Tags: base64, powershell-3.0

I'm attempting to decode an attachment in an email file from base64 and save it to disk.

For testing purposes, this is my code. Where input.txt contains just the base64 encoded data, which is an HTML file.

```
$file = "C:\input.txt"
$data = Get-Content $file
[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($data)) > out.html
```

The decoding works fine, and it generates a new file that contains all of the lines, and is visibly identical to the original attachment. The problem is that the output file is twice the size (actually (filesize*2)+6 bytes, in this case).

Am I decoding this improperly? I've also tried UTF8 instead of ASCII... same result.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well I got it working. Who knew Out-File re-encoded to Unicode by default? Solved by doing the following:

```
$file = "C:\input.txt"
$data = Get-Content $file
[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($data)) | Out-File -Encoding "ASCII" out.html
```

Comment: I suggest `-Encoding "UTF-8"` instead

Comment: Looks like it's `-Encoding "UTF8"`

Answer (score 20):

This one-liner preserves the original encoding of the base64 encoded file, so it will work with binary files such as a PDF or ZIP.  Change `".\input.txt"` and `output.bin` as needed - this will take `.\input.txt`, base 64 decode it, and then write the bytes out to `output.bin` exactly as they were when the file was encoded.

```
$file = ".\input.txt"; [System.Convert]::FromBase64String((Get-Content $file)) | Set-Content output.bin -Encoding Byte
```

Answer (score 20):

On Windows 10, using PowerShell you can do:

```
certutil -decode in.b64 out.txt
```

Comment: This is the best answer. System.Convert is ridiculously slow and never finishes with a 10Mb file. The same file takes about one second with certutil.

Answer (score 4):

Old question, new answer. Solution that preserv newlines

```
// Generate Content
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -f example_rsa
// Encode
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($(Get-Content -Path example_rsa -Encoding utf8 -Raw))) >> encoded
// Decode
[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($(Get-Content -Path encoded -Encoding utf8 -Raw))) >> decoded
```

Comment: Unfortunately, both commands will write the BOM to the file ... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596982/using-powershell-to-write-a-file-in-utf-8-without-the-bom  Use `[IO.File]::WriteAllLines`to avoid it.

Comment: If the base64 is binary data, for example a file. I had to use this:
```[System.Convert]::FromBase64String($VAR) | Set-Content file.zip -Encoding Byte```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but i found another answer.
You can use unicode at the base64 conversion, it will fit after.

```
$file = "C:\temp\input.txt"
$data = Get-Content $file
[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($data)) > out.html
```

Answer (score 1):

This function should behave the same as the linux `base64` command, at least in regards to encoding and decoding. It can also accept values from pipes.

```
function base64
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]
        $str,
        [switch]
        $decode = $false
    )
    if ($decode)
    {
        return [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($str))
    }
    else
    {
        return [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($str))
    }
}
```

```
PS > base64 -decode YXNk
asd
PS > base64 YXNk
WVhOaw==
PS > echo YXNk | base64
WVhOaw==
PS > echo YXNk | base64 -decode
asd
```

[Note that `Get-Content` returns an `Object[]` by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55838807/what-does-get-content-really-output-a-string-or-several-properties#:%7E:text=Using%20Get-Content%20with%20the%20-Raw%20switch%2C%20returns%20the,in.NET%20are%20Objects%20and%20have%20properties%20and%20methods.)

```
PS > $z=Get-Content .\README.md; $z.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Piping this into the func above will only convert the first line.
To convert an entire file, instead use `Get-Content -Raw`

```
Get-Content -Raw README.md | base64
```