# What does Get-Content really output, a string or several properties?

Tags: string, powershell

What does `Get-Content` really output, a string or an object with several properties?  If it's an object, which property contains the string, and can I modify that property?  The file is only one line so I don't have to deal with an object array.

```
PS C:\Users\me> Get-Content input.txt
111

PS C:\Users\me> Get-Content input.txt | Select-Object *

PSPath       : C:\Users\me\input.txt
PSParentPath : C:\Users\me
PSChildName  : input
PSDrive      : C
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
ReadCount    : 1
Length       : 3

PS C:\Users\me> (Get-Content input.txt).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

`-replace` erases all of the extra properties except length:

```
PS C:\Users\me> (Get-Content input.txt) -replace 111, 222 | Select-Object *

Length
------
     3
```

Comment: `Get-Content` produces a list of strings, but adds some information about the file from which the data came to the string objects.

Comment: which property is the string?

Comment: What do you mean "which property is the string"?

Comment: Like the object has the properties PSPath, PSParentPath, PSChildName, PSDrive, PSProvider, ReadCount, Length.  Where is the string contained?

Comment: @js2010 There is no such property. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8): *"A String object is a sequential collection of System.Char objects that represent a string"*. The (base) object itself is the string.

Answer (score 14):

- **`Get-Content` outputs an *array*<sup>[1]</sup> of .NET `[string]` objects, each representing a line from the input file.**
- **However, `Get-Content` also *decorates* these string objects with *additional properties* that provide helpful metadata about where the strings came from.**
- All data-retrieving [PowerShell provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers) cmdlets - `Get-ChildItem`, `Get-Item`, `Get-Content`, ... - do this; specifically they decorate their output objects with the following `NoteProperty` members: `PSPath`, `PSParentPath`, `PSChildName`, `PSDrive`, `PSProvider`.
- This decorating is made possible by a PowerShell-specific (mostly) *invisible helper type*, `[psobject]`, in which .NET objects are wrapped, and which can store additional properties.
- *Typically*, a decorated .NET object behaves as it normally would; e.g., outputting the strings returned by `Get-Content` prints them as-is, with no indicating that they now contain additional properties (from PowerShell's perspective).
- When it comes to *serialization*, however, or making a `[pscustomobject]` clone of an object with `Select-Object *`, or other contexts where *reflection*  (enumeration of properties) is used, these properties do matter and do surface, as shown in your question.

  - When you serialize with `ConvertTo-Json`, for instance, PowerShell also serializes the additional properties and - somewhat artificially - represents the string's *content* as pseudo property `value` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55855052/45375).
  - Accessing `.psobject.BaseObject` on a decorated `[string]` instance - only<sup>[2]</sup> - allows you to *bypass* the PowerShell-added properties on demand, returning just the underlying .NET `[string]` instance (the *base object*).
- The `NoteProperty` members added by provider cmdlets such as `Get-Content` are *instance* members, i.e., they are specific to a given object. (PowerShell's [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml) also allows you to decorate objects at the *type* level).

  - Therefore, when you construct a *new* `[string]` instance, such as by using the `-replace` operator (or, generally, any string operation that returns a *new* string), the new instance does *not* have the additional properties
  - From the perspective of a string operation, even a decorated string is just a string; the added properties are irrelevant in this context. This pattern applies generally: a decorated object can always act as if it were its .NET base object, and in most contexts does.

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, `Get-Content`, as most cmdlets do, *streams* its output objects, i.e. it emits them to the pipeline *one by one*. Only when you *capture* this output (such as by assigning to a variable) is an *array* (`[object[]]`) constructed on demand, assuming the input file contains *two or more lines* - otherwise, the one and only line is captured as itself, not wrapped in an array - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020105/45375) for more information.</sup>

<sup>[2] In PowerShell version 3 and higher, instance ETS members are no longer associated with a given .NET base object's `[psobject]` wrapper, but with the base object itself, using so-called resurrection tables. `[string]` instances are the only exception, for technical reasons, which is why *only* with `[string]` instances do you truly get an *undecorated* object with `.psobject.BaseObject` - for all other types, accessing the base object is effectively a no-op, as the object returned will still surface instance ETS members (too).

However, `.psobject.BaseObject` can still be useful for accessing *members* (properties, methods) of the base object, in case these members are *shadowed* (overridden) by ETS members of the same name.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

The `Get-Content` cmdlet without the `-Raw` switch returns a string array containing all the lines of the text file, split on newline characters.
Using `Get-Content` with the `-Raw` switch, returns the content of the file as a single string, including the newline characters.

Having said that, if (as in your case) the text file contains only one line, PowerShell automatically 'unboxes' the returned array and returns a single string.

Strings in .NET are Objects and have properties and methods.
Try `"abc" | Get-Member` to see what else is there to be found regarding the String object.

If you do `"abc" | Select-Object *`, the output will be

> ```
> Length
> ------
>      3
> ```

PowerShell now only displays the `Length` property of the string.

`Get-Content` however adds extra information to the resulting (string) object as [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) already commented, that all have to do with the file itself. (`PSPath, PSParentPath, PSChildName, PSDrive, PSProvider, ReadCount`). These extra properties are all added as `NoteProperty` and you can see they are added if you do

```
(Get-Content input.txt) | Get-Member
```

This returns an impressive list, but the object is still of type [System.String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8).

When you do a `-replace` action on that string with `(Get-Content input.txt) -replace 111, 222`, the result will be **New** String object that does not have the extra file-related properties anymore. Now it is just a string and as such has nothing to do with where it originally came from.

Hope that explains

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to do something cool like `(get-content file) -replace 111,222 | set-content` or `(get-content file) | set-content -value { $_ -replace 111,222 }`, but it doesn't work easily.

Comment: @js2010 You can still do something very close to that like this: `(Get-Content $file) -replace 111,222 | Set-Content $file`. Here the string value is piped through byValue and the file path is given in the first positional parrameter of [Set-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-6#parameters). All you were missing then was the path since the added Noteproperty `PSPath` from `Get-Content `is not part of the replaced string anymore.

Comment: I also tried it this way, but the file ends up with only the last line.  `(Get-Content $file) | ForEach-Object {
     $_ -replace 111,222 | Add-Member -Name PSPath -Value $_.PSPath -MemberType NoteProperty -PassThru
 } | Set-Content`  It mostly works with `get-content -raw`, except a blank line gets added at the bottom.

Comment: _Having said that, if (as in your case) the text file contains only one line, PowerShell automatically 'unboxes' the returned array and returns a single string._ -- This bites me for an hour at least once every six months when I have a reason to use PowerShell again. Thanks for reminding me. ;)