# Why doesn't this string serialize to a simple JSON string in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

See below both `$a` and `$s` are strings containing the text `"String"` but each serializes differently with ConvertTo-JSON.

Why won't `$s | ConvertToJson` produce `"String"`??

```bsh
PS W:\PowerShell\powowshell> $a="String"
PS W:\PowerShell\powowshell> $a
String
PS W:\PowerShell\powowshell> $a.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object


PS W:\PowerShell\powowshell> $a | ConvertTo-Json
"String"


PS W:\PowerShell\powowshell> $s
String
PS W:\PowerShell\powowshell> $s.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object


PS W:\PowerShell\powowshell> $s | ConvertTo-Json
{
    "value":  "String",
    "required":  "true"
}
```

### Back-Story

`$s` is the `parameterValue` of a `.ps1` inspected with `Get-Help`:

```bsh
PS W:\PowerShell\powowshell> $cmd = (get-help -full W:\PowerShell\powowshell\examples\components\dosdir.ps1).Syntax.syntaxItem[0].parameter
PS W:\PowerShell\powowshell> $cmd | convertto-json
{
    "description":  [
                        {
                            "Text":  "The path to the directory to be listed"
                        }
                    ],
    "parameterValue":  {
                           "value":  "String",
                           "required":  "true"
                       },
...
$s = $cmd.parameterValue
```

**dosdir.ps1**:

```
param(
    [String]$Path
)
CMD /C "DIR /B $Path"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PowerShell's [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml) allows you to decorate any object with *additional* properties (that are directly accessible only to PowerShell code).

If you do so with a `[string]` instance (whether you do it yourself or another command does it for you<sup>[1]</sup>), these additional properties will surface when the object is serialized with `ConvertTo-Json`:

```
# Add a .foo property with value 'bar' to a string.
$decoratedString = 'hi' | Add-Member -PassThru foo bar

# Output the string as-is.
# The added property does NOT show.
$decoratedString

'---'

# Serialize the string to JSON.
# The added property DOES show and the string's actual content
# is presented as pseudo-property .value
$decoratedString | ConvertTo-Json
```

The above yields:

```
hi
---
{
  "value": "hi",
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5797) discusses this surprising behavior.

**Workaround**:

```
# .psobject.BaseObject returns the underlying, undecorated object.
PS> $decoratedString.psobject.BaseObject | ConvertTo-Json
hi
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> As [js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6654942/js2010) points out, the data-retrieving *PowerShell provider cmdlets* - `Get-ChildItem`, `Get-Item`, `Get-Content`, ... - all add a fixed number of `NoteProperty` members to the objects they output, namely `PSPath`, `PSParentPath`, `PSChildName`, `PSDrive`, `PSProvider`.

Therefore, you'll run into the same problem detailed above if you serialize a string that was obtained with `Get-Content`:

```
PS> 'hi' > t.txt; Get-Content t.txt | ConvertTo-Json
{
  "value": "hi",
  "PSPath": "/Users/jdoe/t.txt",
  "PSParentPath": "/Users/jdoe",
  "PSChildName": "t.txt",
  "PSDrive": {
    "CurrentLocation": "Users/jdoe",
    "Name": "/",
    "Provider": {
      "ImplementingType": "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider",
      "HelpFile": "System.Management.Automation.dll-Help.xml",
      "Name": "FileSystem",
      "PSSnapIn": "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core",
...
```

Note that in the case of a string these extra properties are *lost* when a *new* string is constructed, either by string concatenation or by applying a string operator such as `-replace`:

```
# String concatenation
PS> 'hi' > t.txt; (Get-Content t.txt) + '!' | ConvertTo-Json
hi!

# Using -replace
PS> (Get-Content t.txt) -replace 'i', 'o' | ConvertTo-Json
ho
```

Also note that this **per-output-object decorating adds quite a bit of memory and performance overhead**; for `Get-Content`, [GitHub issue #7537](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7537) suggests offering an *opt-out*.

Comment: Note that using '>' '>>' or 'out-file' converts a file's encoding to unicode by default in PS 5, and can even mix encodings.

Comment: I actually find myself using ConvertTo-JSON for debugging purposes to see what a variable "really" is and not what the terminal presents - given that VSCode's watch debugger is itself buggy and won't display many of may variables. Are there better ways of inspecting a variable?

Comment: @Marc: you can use `Select-Object *`, which creates a shallow `[pscustomobject]` clone of the input object with static `NoteProperty` copies of _all_ properties of the input object, all of which render based on the usual rules (<= 4 properties = table, >= 5 = list)
- though note that in the case of strings and primitive types you won't see the input object's intrinsic value. In VSCode you can append `.psobject.properties` to a variable in the Watch window to effectively get the same information, but note that the representation will be one long line.