# A cmdlet which returns multiple objects, what collection type is it, if any? [PowerShell]

Tags: arrays, powershell, collections, powershell-cmdlet

An example of the `Get-ADuser` cmdlet:

```
$Users = Get-ADuser -Filter *
```

It will in most cases return multiple ADuser objects, but what "collection" type is it?
The documentation only says it will returns one or more user objects of Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser.

Tried to use e.g. `($Users -is [System.Collections.ArrayList])` but I cannot nail the "collection" type?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Cmdlets *themselves* typically use *no* collection type in their output**.<sup>[1]</sup>:
They **emit *individual objects* to the *pipeline***, which can *situationally* mean: zero, one, or multiple ones.

This is precisely what `Get-ADUser` does: *the specific number of output objects depends on the arguments that were given*; that is why the  [`Get-AdUser` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser) only mentions scalar type [`ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.aduser) as the output type and states that it "returns one or more" of them.

Generally, **the PowerShell pipeline is designed to be a conduit for a *stream* of objects**, whose count need not be known in advance, with **commands typically outputting objects *one by one*, as soon as they become available**, and with ***receiving* commands typically also processing them *one by one*, as soon as they're being received**. (see [about_Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7)).

---

**It is the PowerShell engine itself that *automatically collects* multiple outputs for you in an `[object[]]` array<sup>[2]</sup> *if needed***, notably if you capture output via a *variable assignment* or use a command call via `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) (or `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--)<sup>[3]</sup>, or `@(...)`, the *array* subexpression operator, discussed in detail below), as an *expression*:

```bash
# Get-ChildItem C:\Windows has *multiple* outputs, so PowerShell
# collects them in an [object[]] array.
PS> $var = Get-ChildItem C:\Windows; $var.GetType().Name
Object[]

# Ditto with (...) (and also with $(...) and always with @(...))
PS> (Get-ChildItem C:\Windows).GetType().Name
Object[]
```

---

**However, if a given command - possibly *situationally* - only outputs a *single* object, you'll then get just that object *itself*** - it is *not* wrapped in an array (unless you use `@(...)` - see below):

```bash
# Get-Item C:\ (always) returns just 1 object.
PS> $var = Get-Item C:\; $var.GetType().Name
DirectoryInfo # *not* a single-element array, 
              # just the System.IO.DirectoryInfo instance itself
```

What can get tricky is that a given command can *situationally* produce either one or multiple outputs, depending on inputs and runtime conditions, so the engine may return either a single object *or* an array.

```bash
# !! What $var receives depends on the count of subdirs. in $HOME\Projects:
PS> $var = Get-ChildItem -Directory $HOME\Documents; $var.GetType().Name
??? # If there are *2 or more* subdirs: an Object[] array of DirectoryInfos.
    # If there is only *one* subdir.: a DirectoryInfo instance itself.
    # (See below for the case when there is *no* output.)
```

**`@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), is designed to eliminate this ambiguity**, if needed:
By wrapping a command in `@(...)`, PowerShell ensures that its **output is *always* collected as `[object[]]`** - even if the command happens to produce just *one* output object or even *none*:

```bash
PS> $var = @(Get-ChildItem -Directory $HOME\Projects); $var.GetType().Name
Object[] # Thanks to @(), the output is now *always* an [object[]] array.
```

With variable assignments, **a potentially more efficient alternative is to use an `[array]` *type constraint*** to ensure that the output becomes an array:

```bash
# Alternative to @(...)
# Note: You may also create a strongly typed array, with on-demand type conversions:
#       [string[]] $var = ...
PS> [array] $var = Get-ChildItem -Directory $HOME\Documents; $var.GetType().Name
Object[]
```

Note:

- This is potentially more efficient in that if the RHS already happens to be an array, it is assigned as-is, whereas **`@(...)` actually *enumerates* the output from `...` and then *reassembles* the elements into a *new* (`[object[]]`) array**.

  - `[array]` *preserves* the specific type of an input array by simply *passing it through* (e.g., `[array] $var = [int[]] (1..3)` stores the `[int[]]` array as-is in `$var`).
  - Note that in edge cases `@(...)` and `[array]` can behave differently: `@($null)` returns a single-item array whose one and only element is `$null`, whereas `[array] $null` has no effect (stays `$null`). Similarly, with a command that produces no output, e.g. `& {}`, `@(& {})` becomes an *empty array*, whereas `[array] $arr = & {}` assigns `$null` (*except*  - due to what is arguably a *bug* - in contexts where variable optimization is disabled, which notably applies to the *global* scope: it is the special "nothing" value (see below) that is then unexpectedly assigned; see [GitHub issue #20275](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20275)).
    A practical consequence is that you can only blindly index into `@(...)` results (assuming that [strict mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) is off, which it is by default, or at most at version `2`), not into `[array] (...)` ones; e.g.: `@(Get-ChildItem nosuch*)[0]` yields `$null` whereas `([array] (Get-ChildItem nosuch*))[0]` *fails*, because you cannot index into `$null`.<sup>Thanks, [Walter A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3220113/walter-a).</sup>
- Placing the `[array]` cast to the *left* of `$var = ...` - which is what it makes it a *type constraint* on the variable - means that the type of the variable is *locked in*, and assigning different values to `$var` later will continue to convert the RHS value to `[array]` (`[object[]]`), if needed (unless you assign `$null` or "nothing" (see below)).

---

Taking a step back: **Ensuring that collected output is an array is often *not necessary***, due to **PowerShell's *unified handling of scalars and collections*** in v3+:

- PowerShell exposes [intrinsic members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members) even on scalar (non-collection) objects that allow you treat them like collections.

  - E.g. `(42).Count` is `1` (`(42).Length` works too); it is treated like an integer *collection* with 1 element, and this also applies to *indexing*: `(42)[0]` is `42`, i.e. the virtual collection's first and only element.
  - *Caveat*: *Type-native* members take precedence, which is a pitfall with *strings*: `'foo'.Length` is `3`, the string's length - but `'foo'.Count` works (is `1`); however, `'foo'[0]` is invariably `'f'`, because the `[string]` type's native indexer returns the individual characters in the array (workaround: `@('foo')[0]`)
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035802/45375) for details.

---

**If a command produces *no* output, you'll get "nothing"** (strictly speaking: the [`[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull) singleton), which **in most cases behaves like `$null`**<sup>[4]</sup>:

```bash
# Get-Item nomatchingfiles* produces *no* output.
PS> $null -eq (Get-Item nomatchingfiles*)
True

# Conveniently, PowerShell lets you call .Count on this value, which the
# behaves like an empty collection and indicates 0.
PS> (Get-Item nomatchingfiles*).Count
0
```

---

<sup>[1] It *is* possible to output entire collections *as a whole* to the pipeline (in PowerShell code with `Write-Output -NoEnumerate $collection` or, more succinctly, `, $collection`), but that is then just another object in the pipeline that happens to be a collection itself. Outputting collections as a whole is an *anomaly*, however, that changes how commands you pipe *to* see the output, which can be unexpected; a prominent example is [`ConvertFrom-Json`s unexpected behavior prior to v7.0](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3424).</sup>

<sup>[2] a [`System.Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array) instance whose elements are of type [`System.Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Object), allowing you to *mix objects of different types* in a single array.</sup>

<sup>[3] Use of `(...)` is usually sufficient; `$(...)` is only needed for string interpolation (expandable strings) and for embedding whole statements or *multiple* commands in a larger expression; note that `$(...)`, unlike `(...)` by itself, unwraps single-element arrays; compare `(, 1).GetType().Name` to `$(, 1).GetType().Name`; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58248195/45375).</sup>

<sup>[4] There are scenarios in which "nothing" behaves differently from `$null`, notably in the pipeline and in `switch` statements, as detailed in [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9997#issuecomment-505296556). [GitHub issue #13465](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13465) is a green-lit enhancement to make "nothing" more easily distinguishable from `$null`, by supporting `-is [System.Management.Automation.AutomationNull]` as
a test; however, as of PowerShell (Core) 7.3.8 no one has stepped up to implement it yet.</sup>

Comment: Instructive answer! You might want to add the next example:
`var = @(Get-Item nomatchingfiles*); $var[0].count` works, and `[array] $var = Get-Item nomatchingfiles*; $var[0].count` shows an error.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's just an object array:

```
$Users.gettype()
$Users.count
$Users -is [object[]]
```

$error is an arraylist:

```
$error -is [collections.arraylist]
```