# Powershell singleton array

Tags: powershell

I need to create a `singleton` complex array. Background: I am trying to automate Let's Encrypt DNS challenge with GoDaddy. But the question is just about PS objects.

Suppose I have the [following JSON object](https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/domains#/v1/recordReplaceTypeName), which is my **target** notation

```
[
  {
    "data": "string",
    "port": 0,
    "priority": 0,
    "protocol": "string",
    "service": "string",
    "ttl": 0,
    "weight": 0
  }
]
```

I try to initialize the variable via Powershell as follows

```
$goDaddyDnsBody=@(
   @{
        "data"= $dnsChallenge;
        "port"= 1;
        "priority"= 0;
        "ttl"= 600;
        "weight"= 0    
    }
)
```

The above code is **supposed** to create an array containing only one item

But when I try to `Write-Host ($goDaddyDnsBody |ConvertTo-Json)` I get only the first element, not the whole array

```
{
  "weight": 0,
  "priority": 0,
  "data": ".................",
  "ttl": 600,
  "port": 1
}
```

The question is obvious: how can I make sure, without necessarily using string manipulation, that the object created is an array?

Comment: As an aside: [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write _to the display only_, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it _by itself_; e.g., `$value` instead of `Write-Host $value` (or use `Write-Output $value`, though that is rarely needed); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great work with the self answer!

I wanted to point out two things:

1. the `-AsArray` parameter to `ConvertTo-Json` was not always available. It's in the current supported versions of PowerShell that are cross-platform. However, it is not available in Windows PowerShell (versions 5.1 and earlier) which many are still using.
2. The original issue stems from using the pipeline with an array that contains a single object. Because the pipeline is "unrolling" the array and passing each object into the cmdlet, with a single object array the cmdlet only ever sees the single object. For more on that, see [mklement0's excellent and detailed explanation in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020105/3905079).

You can instead produce an array by passing the array directly to the parameter:

```
ConvertTo-Json -InputObject @(@{a=1})
```

Result:

```json
[
    {
        "a":  1
    }
]
```

Also worth noting that with the newer `-AsArray` option you don't need the wrapping array at all, in either the direct parameter or pipeline invocations:

```
ConvertTo-Json -InputObject @{a=1} -AsArray
@{a=1}|ConvertTo-Json -AsArray
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself.

The problem is in with the serialization, not with the initialization of the singleton array. I just needed to add the following `-AsArray` switch

```
Write-Host ($goDaddyDnsBody |ConvertTo-Json -AsArray)
```

Sharing for posterity

Comment: Yes, but to add to  [briantist's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65400727/45375): This isn't about _serialization_, but about _enumeration_, which the PowerShell pipeline performs by default; for the rationale behind this behavior, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020105/45375).