# Powershell: Reduce an array of JSON objects to an array of a single object field

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

In Powershell, how do I reduce an array of JSON objects, like this below, into a simple String array of "Name"?    I am NOT encountering this issue with a normal Json-Object (non-array).

```
[
    {
        "Name":"Name1",
        "Id": 3433
    },
    {
        "Name":"Name2",
        "Id": 5455
    }
]
```

Into this:

```
[
    "Name1", 
    "Name2"
]
```

Here is what I am trying to do.   This code does NOT return an array; instead, it returns the value of the first item in the array.

```
function FindServiceBusNamespaces($ResourceGroup) {
    $toExecute = "az servicebus namespace list --resource-group ${ResourceGroup}"
    $response = GetAzResponseObject -Expression "$toExecute"
    $namespaceArray = @()
    foreach ($ns in $response)
    {
        $namespaceArray += $ns | Select-Object -ExpandProperty id
    }
    return $namespaceArray
}
```

And same result with this:

```
function FindServiceBusNamespaces($ResourceGroup) {
    $toExecute = "az servicebus namespace list --resource-group ${ResourceGroup}"
    $response = GetAzResponseObject -Expression "$toExecute"
    $namespaceArray = @()
    foreach ($ns in $response)
    {
        $namespaceArray += $ns.id
    }
    return $namespaceArray
}
```

Comment: Can we see your attempts at this? You can simply expand the property you want and convert it back to JSON after you've converted from JSON.

Comment: `$JsonVar | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what `GetAzResponseObject` returns, it's hard to diagnose your problem, but to answer the question at the start of your post:

```bash
$jsonArr = @'
[
    {
        "Name":"Name1",
        "Id": 3433
    },
    {
        "Name":"Name2",
        "Id": 5455
    }
]
'@

$res = (ConvertFrom-Json $jsonArr).Name

ConvertTo-Json @($res)
```

yields:

```bash
[
  "Name1",
  "Name2"
]
```

Note:

- `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) around `$res` ensures that the value serializes as a JSON *array*, even if `$res` happens to contain only *one* `.Name` value.
- This is necessary, because in the PowerShell [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipelines), which *enumerates* arrays (enumerables in general), a single-element input array effectively turns into its one and only element, i.e. the array wrapper is lost. This behavior also applies to [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration), because `(...).Name` is in essence the same as `... | ForEach-Object { $_.Name }`

Comment: Thanks!  You gave me the hint I needed to solve it.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @djangofan, but please consult with me before making substantial edits to my answer. Please see my update, which - given that you wanted split the single pipeline into multiple steps - uses [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) to extract the `.Name` property values. Also, there's no good reason to use `Write-Host` here, [which is often the wrong tool to use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375).

Comment: @djangofan, I've also added a hint re use of `@(...)`, as I'm now seeing that your original problem may have been about a JSON input array with only a _single_ element turning into _just that element_ in the pipeline, i.e. the array wrapper getting lost.

Comment: yep, thanks.  a wierdness when array comes back with single value

Comment: @djangofan, yes, it's a classic PowerShell pitfall. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020105/45375) has information about the design rationale behind it.