# Convert Raw/space delimited text to an array

Tags: powershell, split

I am working with RAW text  file that  I need to split and create an array. RAW Text file generated based on parameter. $list sent from another program.
My Ps code:

```
param($list)
$path="C:\BU\test\"
New-Item $path\test.txt
Set-Content $path\test.txt "$list" --> Output RAW data Eg:(Apple Orange Kiwi)
$list2=get-Content C:\BU\test\test.txt
$cd=$list.Replace(' ',', ')   
New-Item $path\cd.txt
Set-Content $path\cd.txt "$cd"  
$cd=get-Content C:\BU\test\cd.txt  Output CD Data (Apple, Orange, Kiwi)
```

I am  assuming  If I call $cd[0] using write-host, Output should be Apple, but when I call $cd[0] gets only A. What am I missing ?
thank you for suggestions.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example

Comment: $path="C:\BU\test\"
New-Item $path\test.txt
Set-Content $path\test.txt "apple orange kiwi"
$list2=get-Content C:\BU\test\test.txt
$cd=$list2.Replace(' ',', ')   
New-Item $path\cd.txt
Set-Content $path\cd.txt "$cd"

Comment: imgbb: https://ibb.co/fHwxJmG

Comment: for debug use either 1) Write-Host $list2 or 2) $list2 | Format-Table

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're ultimately trying to do this, using the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator:

```bash
$list = 'Apple Orange Kiwi'
# Split $list into an array of tokens by whitespace.
$cd = -split $list # -> equivalent of @('Apple', 'Orange', 'Kiwi')
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

- [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) by default reads files *line by line*.
- Your input file contains just *one* line, containing verbatim `Apple, Orange, Kiwi`
- Because of how PowerShell collects streaming output from commands, `$cd=get-Content C:\BU\test\cd.txt` stores that single line as a *string* in variable `$cd`, and *not* as an *array* containing that single line as its (only) element.
- Indexing into a *string* returns the *characters* at the specified position(s), which is what you saw:

  ```bash
  $line = 'Apple, Orange, Kiwi'
  $line[0] # -> 'A', i.e. the *first character* of the string
  ```

  - To ensure that `Get-Content` *always* returns an *array*, you can use `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--):

    ```bash
    # $cd[0] then always returns the *first line*.
    $cd = @(Get-Content C:\BU\test\cd.txt)
    ```
  - Alternatively, *type-constrain* the receiving variable with `[array]`

    ```bash
    # [array] is the same as [object[]]
    [array] $cd = Get-Content C:\BU\test\cd.txt
    ```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020105/45375) for more information.