# Powershell error writing writing to all users' registry

Tags: powershell, registry

I'm attempting to add a wallpaper, along with certain parameters, to each user on a computer. It's been hit and miss with this working/not working on computers. The ones that fail I get the error "Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'."

The variables $WallpaperPath and $Style are coming from another source within Automation Manager (using N-Central).

```
# Get each user profile SID and Path to the profile
$UserProfiles = Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\*" | Where {$_.PSChildName -match "S-1-5-21-(\d+-?){4}$" } | Select-Object @{Name="SID"; Expression={$_.PSChildName}}, @{Name="UserHive";Expression={"$($_.ProfileImagePath)\NTuser.dat"}}

# Add in the .DEFAULT User Profile
$DefaultProfile = "" | Select-Object SID, UserHive
$DefaultProfile.SID = ".DEFAULT"
$DefaultProfile.Userhive = "C:\Users\Public\NTuser.dat"
$UserProfiles += $DefaultProfile

# Loop through each profile on the machine</p>
Foreach ($UserProfile in $UserProfiles) {
    # Load User ntuser.dat if it's not already loaded
    If (($ProfileWasLoaded = Test-Path Registry::HKEY_USERS\$($UserProfile.SID)) -eq $false) {
        Start-Process -FilePath "CMD.EXE" -ArgumentList "/C REG.EXE LOAD HKU\$($UserProfile.SID) $($UserProfile.UserHive)" -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden
    }

# Write to the registry
$key = "Registry::HKEY_USERS\$($UserProfile.SID)\Control Panel\Desktop"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -name Wallpaper -value "$WallpaperPath"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -name TileWallpaper -value "0" 
Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -name WallpaperStyle -value "$Style" -Force

# Unload NTuser.dat        
If ($ProfileWasLoaded -eq $false) {
    [gc]::Collect()
    Start-Sleep 1
    Start-Process -FilePath "CMD.EXE" -ArgumentList "/C REG.EXE UNLOAD HKU\$($UserProfile.SID)" -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden| Out-Null
    }
}
```

I'm looking for this to load a temporary HKU hive for each user that's not currently logged in, and has an NTuser.dat file, and write the registry entries specified. It should then unload any hive for users it added.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$UserProfiles = ...`, **use either `[array] $UserProfiles = ...` or `$UserProfiles = @(...)`** in order **to ensure that `$UserProfiles` *always* contains an array**, even if the command happens to return just *one* object.

That way, **your `+=` operation is guaranteed to work** as intended, namely to (loosely speaking) *append an element to the array*.<sup>[1]</sup>

Note that PowerShell's pipeline has no concept of an *array*, just a *stream of objects*. When such a stream is *collected*, a *single* object is captured as itself; only *two or more* objects are captured in an *array* (`[object[]]`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020105/45375) for more information.

A simple demonstration:

```
2, 1 | ForEach-Object {
  $result = Get-ChildItem / | Select-Object Name -First $_
  try {
    $result += [pscustomobject] @{ Name = 'another name' }
    "`$result has $($result.Count) elements."
  } catch {
    Write-Warning "+= operation failed: $_"
  }
}
```

In the first iteration, `2` objects are returned, which are
stored in an array. `+=` is then used to "append" another element.

In the second iteration, only `1` object is returned and stored *as such*.
Since `[pscustomobject]`, which is the type of object returned by [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object), doesn't define a `+` operation (which would have
to be implemented via an `op_Addition()` method at the .NET level), the error you saw occurs.

Using an `[array]` type constraint or `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) operator, avoids this problem:

```
2, 1 | ForEach-Object {
  # Note the use of @(...)
  # Alternatively:
  #   [array] $result = Get-ChildItem \ | Select-Object Name -First $_
  $result = @(Get-ChildItem / | Select-Object Name -First $_)
  $result += [pscustomobject] @{ Name = 'another name' }
  "`$result has $($result.Count) elements."
}
```

As noted, `[array] $results = Get-ChildItem \ | Select-Object Name -First $_` works too, though there are subtle differences between the two approaches - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45091504/45375).

---

As an aside:

- To synchronously execute console applications or batch files and capture their output, call them *directly* (`c:\path\to\some.exe ...` or `& $exePath ...`), do *not* use `Start-Process` (or the `System.Diagnostics.Process` API it is based on) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375). [GitHub docs issue #6239](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239) provides guidance on when use of  `Start-Process` is and isn't appropriate.
- That is, you can just make calls such as the following:

  ```
  REG.EXE LOAD "HKU\$($UserProfile.SID)" "$($UserProfile.UserHive)"
  ```
- Also, it's easier and more efficient to construct `[pscustomobject]` instances with their literal syntax (v3+; see the conceptual [about_PSCustomObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSCustomObject) help topic):

  ```
    $UserProfiles += [pscustomobject] @{
      SID = ".DEFAULT"
      Userhive = "C:\Users\Public\NTuser.dat"
    }
  ```

---

<sup>[1] Technically, a *new* array must be created behind the scenes, given that arrays are fixed-size data structures. While `+=` is convenient, it is therefore *inefficient*, which matters in loops - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375).</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I added [array] to the $UserProfiles like you suggested and it worked without giving that error.

Another note, however, is it didn't run this against the currently logged in user. It ran it against HKU\Default and the users that were not currently logged in, however.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @AdamKohne; I've added some more information to the answer. What ran against `HKU\Default`? Anyway, this is an unrelated problem, right?

Comment: It is a separate issue. The reason it didn't grab the currently logged in user is due to the name of the profile, as it is an Azure profile that starts with "S-1-12-1" vs starting with "S-1-5-21".