# Edit .XML file with Powershell, encoding

Tags: xml, powershell

I need to edit a .xml file with powershell. The thing I need to do is to download the .xml file from the server, updated the version number, and then save it in my local computer. This is what I did.

```
[xml]$myXML = get-content $xmlFileServer
$myXML.'ivy-module'.info.revision = $newVersion
$myXML.Save($newXMLFileName)
```

Then I will have a new xml file in my local computer. However, I doubt the coding is different since I can't process with this .xml file.
The .xml I should get is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
  <info organisation="XXXX" module="XXXX" revision="2.0.1.0" status="release" publication="20131119202217" />
  <publications>
    <artifact name="XXXX" type="dll" ext="zip" conf="*" />
  </publications>
</ivy-module>
```

However, after editing with powershell, the .xml contains some hidden info. I tried to open  with NotePad++, I got something like this:

```
ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
  <info organisation="XXXX" module="XXXX" revision="2.0.1.0" status="release" publication="20131119202217"/>
  <publications>
    <artifact name="XXXX" type="dll" ext="zip" conf="*"/>
  </publications>
</ivy-module>
```

Can anyone tell me why is the situation? 
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"ï»¿" is the [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) for UTF-8. There is a solution for writing a UTF-8 file without the BOM here:
[Using PowerShell to write a file in UTF-8 without the BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596982/using-powershell-to-write-a-file-in-utf-8-without-the-bom)

Comment: Thanks. This works. I only need to add one line of codes. Thank you.

Comment: Could you extend the answer to show how to incorporate the linked solution with an XML file?  `[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($MyPath, $myXML, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)` simply prints out "System.Xml.XmlDocument".  I would rather not have to write it once with $myXML.Save() then reread it in again to save without the BOM.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me, based on the link above and on [this blog post](http://allen-mack.blogspot.ca/2006/11/omitting-byte-order-mark-while-saving.html)

```
$enc = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding( $false )
$wrt = New-Object System.XML.XMLTextWriter( 'c:\path\out.xml', $enc )
$wrt.Formatting = 'Indented'
$myXML.Save( $wrt )
$wrt.Close()
```

The 'Indented' setting is personal taste; I prefer my XML human readable.  The $wrt.Close() is also required.

Comment: NB: This works for me; but to have text editors recognise that the file is `UTF-8` and not `ANSI` I had to use `$true` for the `encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier` parameter on `UTF8Encoding`'s constructor.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in PowerShell 5.1. I get "Multiple ambiguous overloads found for 'Save' and the argument count '1'."

Comment: Only thing that worked for me was using a StreamWriter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30266424/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reading the xml using get-content, read the xml using the XmlDocument directly:

function test($path)
{

```
$xDoc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$file = Resolve-Path($path)

$xDoc.Load($file)
$xDoc.Save($file) #will save correctly
```

}

Comment: `$xDoc.Load($file)` doesn't work if the XML file doesn't already contain a BOM – it actually throws an exception complaining about the missing BOM.