# How can I Force or Specify Encoding type using Xml.Save?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML configuration file I am modifying with PowerShell, and when I save the file using Xml.Save it changes the encoding type.

When I open the ORIGINAL file I am trying to edit in Notepad++  the encoding type is listed as "UTF-8 without BOM". When I open the file in Notepad++ AFTER editing using Xml.Save the encoding type is listed simply as "UTF-8". This causes the program using this file to error out saying it can't parse to config properties.

If I open the EDITED file in Notepad++, change the encoding type to "UTF-8 without BOM", and save the file. The program will then run without error.

How can I force and or specify the `Xml.Save` to use the "UTF-8 without BOM" encoding type when saving the file?

I have tried different ways of casting and saving file, but `Xml.Save` seems to default to the "UTF-8" enconding type.

```psh
$xml = New-Object -TypeName XML
$xml.Load($file)
$xml.configuration.config.option = $newValue
$xml.Save($file)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This appears to take care of it. There could certainly be more elegant ways...

```
$xml = New-Object -TypeName XML
$xml.Load($file)
$xml.configuration.config.option = $newValue

$utf8WithoutBom = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($false)
$sw = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($file, $false, $utf8WithoutBom)

$xml.Save( $sw )
$sw.Close()
```

Details collected from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074648/when-saving-an-xmldocument-it-ignores-the-encoding-in-the-xmldeclaration-utf8), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074648/when-saving-an-xmldocument-it-ignores-the-encoding-in-the-xmldeclaration-utf8) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437666/write-text-files-without-byte-order-mark-bom).

Comment: Interesting! I found a similar solution that basically uses the same method. It does work, but the interesting part is that after I save the file, and open it in Notepad++, it lists the file as having an "ANSI" encoding. Like you said I was hoping for something more elegant, but this does work, so thank you!

Comment: @user1770228 I came up with the same solution when I answered your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30263775/1630171). I opened the output file from my tests in Notepad++ and it showed "UTF-8 without BOM" as the encoding.

Comment: Worked for me. Notepad++ says "Utf8" after saving. But without it was "Utf8 BOM"