# Notepad++ opening files containing En dash character

Tags: notepad++

I have two files with identical content. One file has an XML extension, the other txt. Both files are encoded in ASCII. They both contain the En dash character (hex value 96).

When I open the file with the txt extension the file displays as I would expect. The En dash correctly shows as a dash.

When I open the XML file, however, the En dash character displays as x96 in inverted foreground/background colours.

Does this display of the xml file have to do with the fact that it's an ASCII encoded file but the file contains:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Why does the character not display correctly? When I hex edit the XML file I see the En dash is hex value 96 which is still within the extended ASCII table.

File sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<x>Plug &amp; Play ֠No wire splicing necessary</x>
```

The en dash follows "Play " and precedes " No". Please note the leading and trailing space.

Comment: The same XML file opens and displays correctly using Microsoft's Notepad. If from Notepad I save the XML file using UTF-8 encoding the resulting file can be opened and displayed correctly using Notepad++.

I would further observe that opening the ASCII XML file in Notepad++ then doing Encoding > Encode in UTF-8, or Encoding > Convert to UTF-8 has no affect on how the file displays.

Comment: Are you using the XML plugin for Notepad++?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I observe the same behavior using XML Tools with Notepad++ as I do with an install of Notepad++ without any XML related plugins.

Comment: Can you post a sample line of text and an XML snippet that contain the values that we can use for testing this issue?

Comment: When I copy the XML from your comment and paste it into NP++, it appears correctly. When I change the language to XML, it properly syntax highlights and remains correct in appearance.

Comment: @kenwhite
Look at the sample in my original question. After the word "play" is a single space, then the en dash, followed by another space then the word "No".

Comment: I still don't see what you're claiming to see. (I don't see en-dash, but I'm also not seeing the hex value you're describing.) Have you opened the XML file in a hex editor and confirmed that it's actually 0x96 in that position? (That's also not the word No; look at what you're indicating is the **N** more closely or in a larger font. I'm suspecting you're not really getting the data you think you're getting.)

Comment: @KenWhite
Please see the sample files I linked to in my question. I also give you two reference images showing how my install of Notepad++ displays the file, and the screenshot of the hex version of the file.

Comment: I think it may be a Notepad++ bug. Sometimes, but not always, when I use the Hex-Editor addon to view the file in hex, then revert the en dash displays correctly. Other times it seems if I open the file, it displays correctly, if I then close the file and open it again the file displays x96 in inverted colours.

Comment: Sorry. Content that is not in the question itself doesn't exist. If the off-site location isn't available (off-line, moved, deleted, etc.), the question loses it's value to future readers here. If you can't provide the details needed for us to reproduce the problem here, then the question needs to be closed as non-reproduceable.

Comment: @KenWhite Create an ASCII encoded XML file that contains a character with decimal 96 byte value, then open said file in Notepad++. This is how you reproduce the issue. If you can't generate the file yourself, what option have I other than providing a link to a sample file? A link which is currently valid, so you could at least click the link and at least *you* could see what I mean.

Comment: I've told you already that I copied and pasted your XML sample (which presumably contains that exact content), and cannot reproduce the error. (I've also pointed out that the values you claim to be getting do not match what you provided in that sample content). You can't even report it as a bug in NP++ if you can't provide a way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: And the link being valid **now** is irrelevant. What matters is whether the link will be valid next month or next year or five years from now when a future reader here is searching for a solution to a problem. Questions need to contain *all relevant content here, in the question itself*.

Comment: Something is wrong with your assumptions. En-dash is not a member of the ASCII character set and the ASCII encoding does not produce the byte 0x96 ever. There is no one "extended ASCII table" so it is really not a very useful term. It seems like you are guessing at the encoding. The encoding is exactly what the producer of the file used when writing the file. It doesn't matter what anybody or anything thinks it is. In the case of XML, the optional, internally specified encoding should match, which is one way of satisfying the requirement of communicating to the reader which encoding to use.

Comment: @TomBlodget The file is being produced by VB6 using Scripting.FileSystemObject.CreateTextFile. The Unicode parameter is set to false. The MSDN states the resulting file will be ASCII. The contents are being wrote to the file with the Write method of the stream which CreateTextFile returns. I know the encoding because *I* wrote the file.

Comment: I'm quite sure they mean ANSI rather than ASCII. ANSI is a reference to the thread's current ANSI Code Page (ACP), which is initialized from a system-side setting. Windows-1252, for example, but it can vary from time to time and system to system. I recommend passing true for Unicode (UTF-16) to avoid the dependence on extrinsic settings.

Comment: @TomBlodget The people we produce the XML files for distribute them to others who can't parse the file when Unicode encoded, we tried that route previously.

Comment: (Very odd because, regardless of the document encoding, XML characters are from the Unicode character set.) This seems like an [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please take us up a few thousand feet and I'm sure we can help you.

Comment: @TomBlodget I have produced an XML file using Microsoft's Scripting.FileSystemObject.CreateTextFile using Writeline and Write calls. The resulting XML document in Notepad++ appears fine except in inverted colours I see x96. I open my Hex-Editor addon and see the byte in question has value 0x96. The same XML file displays correctly in Microsoft's Notepad (I see the En Dash character). Testing has shown that if I re-open the same file in Notepad++ several times, or sometimes when I switch to Hex mode and back in Notepad++ (using Hex-Editor) the character displays correctly. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an invalid XML file. I don't think there is a universally accepted correct behavior of an editor in such cases. Notepad is interpreting it as a text file. Notepad++ is trying to interpret it as a valid XML file and pointing out the problem.

The reason that Notepad succeeds if you use the Open dialog is that you telling it the encoding of the file: "ANSI". If you use drag and drop or other means, it's either guessing an encoding that's apparently close enough or always using "ANSI".

Notepad++ is helping you more because it's not just a general text editor. It is interpreting the file as an XML file (probably based on the extension).

An XML document optionally indicates the encoding used for its byte representation. You are writing the file as some ANSI encoding (maybe Windows-1252), yet marking it as as UTF-8. That requires XML processors to use UTF-8. (Due to similarities in encodings, a program can read using a guessed encoding to find the indicated encoding and the read the document again using that.)

You luck out here because instead of the wrong encoding resulting in the silent error of scrambling characters, your data actually shows up as invalid. UTF-8 does not produce or allow arbitrary sequences bytes with values 0-255. 0x96 is only allowed if it is part of a sequence and pattern of bytes that encode certain Unicode codepoints. Simply, the file is not valid UTF-8. Notepad++ highlight the bytes that prove that. You would be unlucky if the attempt to read the file as UTF-8 succeeded yet gave an unexpected result.

The solution is to match the indicated encoding to the actual encoding. Normally, XML libraries have writer functions that do this for you. The problem is that you are using a writer that doesn't and you don't actually know which "ANSI" encoding you are using. It seems that you also have a requirement to not use UTF-16. Perhaps you should get a positive statement of what you can use. If you use a post-processing step many tools such as [PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30266424/2226988) could rewrite the XML file for you using a document encoding that you specify.