# Edit a XML file with Powershell kills the encoding

Tags: xml, powershell, iso-8859-1

With Powershell 3.0, I want to edit some XML file created by a programm :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<Node1>
    <Child attr="&#x0A;" />
</Node1>
```

Used script :

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Test.xml" -Force)

# Save it directly :
$xml.Save("C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Test2.xml")

# Force encoding :
$encoding = [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('ISO-8859-1') #
$writer = New-Object IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Test3.xml",$false,$encoding)

$xml.Save($writer)
$writer.Close()
```

Test2.xml and Test3.xml (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30265973/how-can-i-force-or-specify-encoding-type-using-xml-save)) become :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Node1>
  <Child attr="&#xA;" />
</Node1>
```

`&#x0A;` is replaced with `&#xA;`

Why ?
How can I avoid it ? (The programm can't read the edited file).

Comment: Changing the way you output it wont help, the `0` gets truncated when the `[xml]` object is created.

Comment: Why? Because that's valid XML and `&#0xA;` is not. See the W3C Specification ["Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition), section on character references"](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-charref) - a character reference can begin with `&#` or `&#x` only. So, not `&#0x`. That follows up to ["XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes Second Edition" whitespace note](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#rf-whiteSpace) saying "*Note: #xA used here [represents line feed] This notation is to be distinguished from &#xA;, which is the XML character reference to that same UCS code point.*".

Comment: So the programm can't read valid XML, report to their support, file a bug, etc. Or find another XML library which is broken in a conveniently compatible way, or write an XML stream writer which picks out that case and changes it, or reload the file as text after saving and do some text search/replace because you have no other choice...

Comment: OK thank you for the explanation.