# Some files not analyzed by Sonar "Invalid character encountered in file"

Tags: c#, utf-8, sonarqube, code-analysis

I have a couple of files that are not analyzed with the following message:

> Invalid character encountered in file [file name with full path] at
>   line 9 for encoding UTF-8. Please fix file content or configure the
>   encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'.

In Visual Studio when I select File / Advance Save Options, the files were set to Western Europe (Windows) - Codepage 1252.

I changed it to Unicode (UTF-8 with Signature) - Codepage 65001.

But SonarQube still complains about the invalid characters. The "invalid characters" are comments in German with Umlaut-characters (ä,ö,ü)

What can I do to fix this (without removing the comments)?

Comment: I also have the same problem after upgrading to SonarQube 5.6.6 - same problem with German umlauts. sonar.sourceEncoding = UTF-8 is set - the ue-umlaut is CEBC in hex editor, so everything should be ok - how did you solve your problem?

Comment: I used a script from the following [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596982/using-powershell-to-write-a-file-in-utf-8-without-the-bom). That works well with C#. If you have C++ sources as well, you might need to convert to UTF-8 with BOM. For that I used a Powershell script UTF8-EncodeFilesWithBOM  `$basePath = "C:\Main\System"

foreach($line in Get-Content "C:\Temp\utf\utfErrors2.txt") {
  $file = Join-Path -Path $basePath -ChildPath $line
  (Get-Content $file -Encoding UTF8) | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 $file
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild and the SonarQube C# plugin currently expect all files of the project to have the UTF-8 encoding - and this is hardcoded.

There is a ticket to improve this in a future version: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-174

Comment: How come it still did not work after changing the encoding to UTF-8?

Comment: I suspect that the file's encoding has not been properly changed. You can have a look at line 9 of that file in a hexadecimal editor to see for yourself whether it looks correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error `Invalid Character encountered in file` when `XML` files were analyzed. And I already had `sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8` in my properties file.

The problem was I didn't have XML plugin installed in Sonar. Once I installed that via `Update Center`, this issue for resolved. Hope this helps anyone else facing this issue.