# Powershell – WriteAllLines method – ‘Access is Denied’

Tags: .net, powershell, utf-8

I am attempting to convert the format of a file to UTF-8 with PowerShell using a   [technique outlined in another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596982/using-powershell-to-write-a-file-in-utf-8-without-the-bom/#answer-5596984).

I am using the following statement:

```
[IO.File]::WriteAllLines((Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName,"Test.txt")
```

The first parameter is the file path (C:\users\rsax\documents\Test), and the second parameter is the name of the file.

However, the command is not working, and is returning the following error:

```
Exception calling "WriteAllLines" with "2" argument(s): "Access to the path 'C:\users\rsax\documents\Test' is denied."
At line:1 char:25
+ [IO.File]::WriteAllLines <<<< ((Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName,"Test.txt")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

- I am running the command from PowerShell as an administrator.
- I have verified that the file is in the folder.
- I can run other cmdlets in the directory that access the file, such
  as:

  Get-Content Test.txt | Out-File TestOut.txt
- I was not able to find an answer on the [MSDN
  MethodInvocationException page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.methodinvocationexception(v=vs.85).aspx).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first argument should be the full path, not just the directory. The second argument is the source content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure you understand the overload you're using. The first argument is supposed to be the filepath, while the second is the content (not the filename). `(Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName` will be the path of the folder, not the file. Also, the `-Verbose` switch is not needed.

```
PS> [IO.File]::WriteAllLines.OverloadDefinitions
static void WriteAllLines(string path, string[] contents)
```

Sample:

```
$content = Get-Content .\Test.txt
$outfile = Join-Path (Get-Item -Path ".\Test.txt").DirectoryName "TestOut.txt"
[IO.File]::WriteAllLines($outfile, $content)
```

Comment: You are right - I didn't understand the overload. Thank you for the solution -- it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

`WriteAllLines` takes the full path of the file, and then the lines of text to write. Don't separate the file parts. Also notice that you are not telling it *what* to write at all.

```
$content = 'a','b','c'
$path = (Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName | Join-Path -ChildPath 'Test.txt'
[IO.File]::WriteAllLines($path,$content)
```

Comment: `Get-Item -Path ".\Test.txt"` will fail if file not yet exist.