# Create properties file without BOM

Tags: powershell, utf-8, powershell-2.0, byte-order-mark

I am trying to create a properties file using PowerShell 2.0.

I am using following operations:

```
echo SLAVE1=$MAIN_DB >result.properties
echo SLAVE2=$WB_DB >>result.properties
```

But the file is getting created in wrong encoding (I believe "With BOM"). Is there any way I can do my above operation and created file is in UTF-8 encoding without BOM?

Comment: I found the solution [here](http://superuser.com/questions/397890/convert-text-files-recursively-to-utf-8-in-powershell). Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

With your code, PowerShell 5.0 and Windows 10 I get UCS-2 LE BOM as encoding for the written file.

Try:

```
echo SLAVE1=$MAIN_DB | Out-File result.properties -Encoding utf8
echo SLAVE2=$WB_DB | Add-Content .\result.properties
```

The Cmdlets 'Out-File' and 'Add-Content' have both the -Encoding Parameter here you can choose between "Unicode", "UTF7", "UTF8", "UTF32", "ASCII", "BigEndianUnicode", "Default", and "OEM".

If the encoding in result is not the one that you want I think you've to use the .Net Classes like shown in [Using PowerShell to write a file in UTF-8 without the BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596982/using-powershell-to-write-a-file-in-utf-8-without-the-bom)