# .gitignore not ignoring node_modules

Tags: git

Even after adding the `.gitignore` file to the root of the `.git` repository, I cannot make git ignore the `node_modules` directory.

The files have not been added for Git to track.

I have gone through earlier stack overflow questions, and also tried adding a comment line to the first line, since apparently Git doesn't read the first line of that file, and it still doesn't work. I have tried to use the following command also, with no avail:

```
git rm --cached -r .
```

Could anyone help me out? The content of `.gitignore`:

```
#first line
node_modules/
```

Comment: Did you put `.gitignore` inside `.git` or inside the directory containing the `.git` directory?

Comment: inside the .git

Comment: I had this issue and it was because the changes were staged from a stash restore after temporarily switching to a branch that didn't have the gitignore...unstaging was the facepalm but correct solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Even after adding the .gitignore file to the root of the .git repository, I cannot make git ignore the node_modules directory.

The `.gitignore` file should be placed in the root of the working tree (also known as the root of your project), which is just above the `.git` directory. Inside the `.git` directory the file has no effect.

This makes sense, because normally you want to put this file under version control, to share the list of ignored files with all developers on the project. And only the files inside the working tree, outside `.git` are under version control, the `.git` directory is for Git's internal storage.

(If you wanted to ignore patterns only locally, without adding to version control, you could do so by defining patterns in `.git/info/exclude`.)

> [...] and also tried adding a comment line to the first line, since apparently Git doesn't read the first line of that file

For the record, it does read the first line too, there's nothing special about the first line in `.gitignore`.

Comment: If you already started versioning the node_modules, remember to `git rm --cached <files>`, this will remove them from the cache and will start reading the new/updated `.gitignore`

Answer (score 26):

I don't know if this will help anyone but I created my .gitignore file in PS with echo "" > .gitignore and thus the encoding was set to UTF-16LE and not UTF-8. This caused problems with .gitignore working properly.

Comment: Okay, but how do we change this? This solution simply explains a potential problem, but still offers no solution. It's like saying, you're car has a problem with the spark plugs in the engine block, and then walking out of the room immediately.

Comment: I agreed so hard I did the sleuthing.  The second comment on this answer is what would do it.  Having said that it's probably easiest to just use the gui and re-create the file via context menu https://stackoverflow.com/a/5596984/364632

Comment: You the GOAT dude. 
I created a file using windows fs and created it in a UTF-16LE. 
I created the .gitignore using VSCode and it was UTF-8, problem fixed.

Answer (score 15):

If all fail you might want to try this. I was having the same issue and nothing worked.

Delete your node_modules folder.
Push the changes to github (if you need to remove the node_modules folder from the repo)
Make sur you have the node_modules/ line in the .gitignore file
Run npm install.
Push again.

I was working under Visual Studio Code and notice that you have to make the gitignore file before you run npm install. Not sure why but it fixed it in my case.

Comment: This was the one for me. What actually happened is that I accidentally committed the node_modules to my branch (oops!). I needed to delete the modules folder, update my ignore file to add include the modules folder, commit the deletion of the folder as well as the new gitignore, then run `npm i` once again and all was well

Answer (score 11):

I solved the problem by deleting the file name at `.gitignore` and made it an invisible file respectively a dot-file, just like naming the file `.gitignore` and keeping the expression

> `node_modules/`

in that file, so that works and now git ignores finally the node-modules directory. Don't know exactly, why this is working, but at least it does.

Answer (score 5):

I deleted my node_modules folder and committed my changes. Then I copied the contents of my .gitignore file and deleted it. Recreated the file, pasted back in my clipboard contents and ran *npm i* . Fixed the issue. I am guessing that if you work on a VM or remote desktop and are using windows than bring the repo onto a mac it can cause encoding errors like mentioned above.

In Short:

copy .gitignore contents

delete .gitignore

re-create .gitignore

paste in clipboard.

Voila

Answer (score 3):

In my case, solved by converting file encoding from 'Unicode' to 'UTF-8 Without BOM' since I created `.gitignore` file via Powershell by redirecting output.

Initially I changed line ending from Windows (CRLF) to Linux (LF), but did not help.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i had it written with quotation marks like this

```
'functions/node_modules/'
```

instead of

```
functions/node_modules/
```

Answer (score 1):

My project structure was as follows:

```
project_name
 |
 |__ client
 |      |_ node_modules/
 |
 |__ server

$ sudo nano .gitignore 

Changed # dependencies 
        /node_modules to client/node_modules

$ git add .     /* to add modified gitignore file */
$ git status    /* to observe changes */
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I created two ".gitignore"  file one in the main directory and second in the client folder

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you always have a new line at the end of your file. Might be helpful for you if you forgot one after your `node_modules/` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was ' node_modules/' instead of 'node_modules/' the space before node_modules was the problem

Answer (score 0):

for me, in my yarn project, this worked fine.

```
yarn cache clean
```

Answer (score -1):

#### This is for whose who cames for a solution like me and non of the above worked

> All I did is removing the ***.git/*** and ***node_modules/*** folder and then i redid the commands `git init` `git add .` ... etc and than i pushed my dir with no problem.