# How to expand file content with powershell

Tags: powershell, variable-expansion, file-encodings

I want to do this :

```
$content = get-content "test.html"
$template = get-content "template.html"
$template | out-file "out.html"
```

where template.html contains

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    $content
  </body>
</html>
```

and test.html contains:

```
<h1>Test Expand</h1>
<div>Hello</div>
```

I get weird characters in first 2 characters of out.html :

```
    ��
```

and content is not expanded.

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42537095/45375) with a solution that:

- is more efficient.
- ensures that the input files are read as UTF-8, even if they don't have a (pseudo-)[BOM (byte-order mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8).
- avoids the "weird character" problem altogether by writing a UTF-8-encoded output file *without that pseudo-BOM*.

```
# Explicitly read the input files as UTF-8, as a whole.
$content =  get-content -raw -encoding utf8 test.html
$template = get-content -raw -encoding utf8 template.html

# Write to output file using UTF-8 encoding *without a BOM*.
[IO.File]::WriteAllText(
  "$PWD/out.html",
  $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($template)
)
```

- `get-content -raw` (PSv3+) reads the files in *as a whole*, into a *single string* (instead of an *array* of strings, line by line), which, while more memory-intensive, is faster. With HTML files, memory usage shouldn't be a concern.

  - An additional advantage of reading the files in full is that if the template were to contain *multi-line* subexpressions (`$(...)`), the expansion would still function correctly.
- `get-content -encoding utf8` ensures that the input files are interpreted as using character encoding UTF-8, as is typical in the web world nowadays.

  - This is crucial, given that **UTF-8-encoded HTML files normally do *not* have the 3-byte pseudo-BOM that PowerShell needs in order to correctly identify a file as UTF-8-encoded** (see below).
- A single `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString()` call is then sufficient to perform the template expansion.
- `Out-File -Encoding utf8` would invariably create a file *with* the pseudo-BOM, which is undesired.
  Instead, **[`[IO.File]::WriteAllText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx) is used, taking advantage of the fact that the .NET Framework *by default* creates UTF-8-encoded files *without* the BOM**.

  - Note the use of `$PWD/` before `out.html`, which is needed to ensure that the file gets written in *PowerShell*'s current location (directory); unfortunately, what the .NET Framework considers the current directory is *not* in sync with PowerShell.

Finally, the obligatory security warning: use this expansion technique only on input that you trust, given that arbitrary embedded commands may get executed.

---

#### Optional background information

PowerShell's `Out-File`, `>` and `>>` use [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) LE character encoding with a [BOM (byte-order mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) by default (the "weird characters", as mentioned).

While **`Out-File -Encoding utf8`** allows creating UTF-8 output files instead,
PowerShell **invariably prepends a 3-byte [pseudo-BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8)** to the output file, which some utilities, notably those with Unix heritage, have problems with - so **you would *still* get "weird characters"** (albeit different ones).

If you want **a more PowerShell-like way of creating BOM-less UTF-8 files**, 
see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34969243/45375) of mine, which defines an `Out-FileUtf8NoBom` function that otherwise emulates the core functionality of `Out-File`.

Conversely, **on *reading* files, you must use `Get-Content -Encoding utf8` to ensure that BOM-less UTF-8 files are recognized as such.**
**In the absence of the UTF-8 pseudo-BOM, `Get-Content` assumes that the file uses the single-byte, extended-ASCII encoding specified by the system's *legacy codepage*** (e.g., [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) on English-language systems, an encoding that PowerShell calls `Default`).

Note that while Windows-only editors such as Notepad create UTF-8 files *with* the pseudo-BOM (*if* you explicitly choose to save as UTF-8; default is the legacy codepage encoding, "ANSI"), **increasingly popular cross-platform editors such as [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), [Atom](https://atom.io/), and [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) by default do *not* use the pseudo-BOM when they create files.**

Answer (score 3):

For the "weird characters", they're probably BOMs (Byte-order marks). Specify the output encoding explicitly with the `-Encoding` parameter when using `Out-File`, for example:

```
$Template |Out-File out.html -Encoding UTF8
```

For the string expansion, you need to explicitly tell powershell to do so:

```
$Template = $Template |ForEach-Object {
    $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_)
}
$Template | Out-File out.html -Encoding UTF8
```