# Powershell cannot expand this javascript content

Tags: javascript, powershell

Applying the answer to my previous question [How to expand file content with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536935/how-to-expand-file-content-with-powershell)

I stumbled upon a fatal error when trying to expand this :

test.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.mylink').click(function(event) {
        var hash = $(this).attr("href");
    });
    // $var
</script>
```

test.ps1

```
$test = get-content -raw test.html
$var = "test"

# Write to output file using UTF-8 encoding *without a BOM*.
[IO.File]::WriteAllText(
  "$PWD/out.html",
  $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($test)
)
```

Comment: 1) What's the question, and 2) what's the error?

Comment: `$` is a special symbol in PS and `$()` denotes an inlined expression so you'll need to escape it before expansion: ```expandString(($test -replace '\$\(', '`$('))```

Comment: @wOxxOm how do you expand a powershell $var if you replace all $ ?

Comment: Hmm, vars isn't a problem because my suggestion is to replace `$(` which cannot be a part of an identifier. However, if you use PowerShell's `$()` then it's a problem that would require a smarter replacement algorithm to differentiate between jQuery and PS.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` is a special symbol in PowerShell and `$()` denotes an inlined expression expanded with its contents so you'll need to escape it before expansion by adding a backtick `` ` `` before `$(`:

```
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString(($test -replace '\$\(', '`$('))
```

However, if you use PowerShell's `$()` in the template then it's a problem that would require a smarter replacement and probably much more complex algorithm to differentiate between jQuery and PS.

Comment: I don't understand why it works except for   app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $window, $sce) {} which gives empty var for $scope, $windows and $sce:    app.controller('Ctrl', function(, , ) {}

Comment: Your original question is about preventing expansion of `$()` expressions which is why the answer deals only with that.