# StreamWriter encoding issues with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, character-encoding

This is a three part question, all related. The context is this: I have a need to do find and replace in arbitrary files, which can potentially have varied encoding, and can potentially be VERY large (upwards of 500 MB). My current code uses Get-Content and Add-Content, and it's both a memory hog and horribly non performant on large files.

I have code that successfully identifies the source file encoding using

```
$reader = [IO.StreamReader]::New($sourceFile, $true)
$reader.Peek() > $null
$encoding = $reader.CurrentEncoding
```

The result is in the form ***System.Text.UTF8Encoding***

1: I believe a Constructor in this form is what I need for the StreamWriter

```
$writer = [IO.StreamWriter]::New($tempFile, Encoding.UTF8)
```

I am hoping there is a built in programatic way to get from the string *System.Text.UTF8Encoding* to the correct form needed for the Constructor. Or do I need to make my own hash table or find/replace to handle this?

2: I have used Encoding.UTF16 in a test, but the resultant file is still UTF8. I recently was educated on the subtlety of StreamReader not populating `.CurrentEncoding` until some kind of Read happens (thus the `.Peek()` in the code above) and I wonder if there is some similar issue with StreamWriter?

3: My understanding is that some encodings need an end of file written, but some don't. For example, when writing a UTF8 file, the file sizes don't match until `$writer.WriteLine("`r`n")` is included as the last WriteLine. Can anyone point me to a reference that spells out which encodings need what endings?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596982/using-powershell-to-write-a-file-in-utf-8-without-the-bom#5596984), which got me started. And, when `$reader.CurrentEncoding` is *System.Text.UTF8Encoding* then `$encoding = New-Object $reader.CurrentEncoding $False` works, but when `$reader.CurrentEncoding` is *System.Text.UTF32Encoding* I get an error about

> Cannot find an overload for "UTF32Encoding"

Which seems odd, because this can't be a typo or something, I am getting the string programmatically from the file.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) suggests that all of these should work, I think. But only the first works. All the rest throw the Overload error.

```
$encoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False
$encoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF32Encoding $False
$encoding = New-Object System.Text.ASCIIEncoding $False
$encoding = New-Object System.Text.UNICODEEncoding $False
```

PROGRESS
So, it seems that the $false in those New-Objects are for the -strict argument, which only applies with -comObject. And only System.Text.UTF8Encoding works as a COM object. All of them work with the -typeName argument, which doesn't have a -strict argument. So...

```
$encoding = New-Object -typeName:System.Text.UTF8Encoding
$encoding = New-Object -typeName:System.Text.UTF32Encoding
$encoding = New-Object -typeName:System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
$encoding = New-Object -typeName:System.Text.UNICODEEncoding
```

works. Also, I changed the StreamWriter Constructor to this

```
$writer = [IO.StreamWriter]::New($destinationFile, $true, (New-Object $reader.CurrentEncoding))
```

That boolean keeps the stream open.
And... at this point I think I have a working function!

Comment: Does `$writer = [IO.StreamWriter]::New($tempFile, $reader.CurrentEncoding)` work? or `$reader.CurrentEncoding.GetEncoder()` ?

Comment: What encoding are you aiming for?  The carriage return + newline is a Windows thing.  In PowerShell, you should use the proper escapes (`\`r\`n`)

Comment: @gvee `$reader.CurrentEncoding` definitely doesn't work, as that produces a string, not the required object. `$reader.CurrentEncoding.GetEncoder()` doesn't throw an error, but it produces a UTF8 file, even when `$reader.CurrentEncoding` = *System.Text.UTF32Encoding*. And as I added in the original post, I am seeing errors with a different approach and *System.Text.UTF32Encoding* when *System.Text.UTF8Encoding* works fine.

Comment: @TheIncorrigable1 Sorry, I didn't notice that my cut n paste didn't copy correctly. I am indeed using ``r`n`. As for encoding, I want to support any valid Windows encoding, since I am working with unknown files. Is this something I can/should add for any encoding, or am I correct it's only needed for some?

Comment: And I still didn't get good formatting. I guess I need more escapes to get it to format right in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to compress all that into a more succinct answer...

```
$reader = [IO.StreamReader]::New($sourceFile, $true)
$reader.Peek() > $null
$writer = [IO.StreamWriter]::New($destinationFile, $true, (New-Object -typeName:$reader.CurrentEncoding))
```

This works a treat.

The question of which encodings need special end of file treatment is still open.