# Lexical Error while parsing JSON file for chef-client

Tags: json, powershell, chef-infra

I am creating a JSON file using powershell and using the JSON file as a chef-runtime attribute.

Code to create JSON file (in powershell)

```
New-Item $ATTRIBUTESFILE -ItemType file
$jsonInput = @{param1=@{subparam=$attribute}}
$ATTRIBUTE = $jsonInput | ConvertTo-Json
$ATTRIBUTE | Out-File $ATTRIBUTESFILE
```

Code to call the chef-client

```
chef-client -o 'recipe[cookbook]' -j $ATTRIBUTESFILE
```

Error message

```
c:/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0-x86-mingw32/lib/yajl.rb:36:in `parse': lexical error:
invalid char in json text. (Yajl::ParseError)
                                   ÿ_{                     (right here) ------^
    from c:/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0-x86-mingw32/lib/yajl.rb:36:in `parse'
    from c:/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/json_compat.rb:56:in `from_json'
```

When I create the same file manually, it gives no lexical error.
Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows PowerShell creates UTF-16LE-encoded files (with a BOM) with `Out-File` and `>` by default.<sup>[1]</sup>

By contrast, Chef requires UTF-8-encoded files without a BOM, according to [coderanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78722/coderanger).
Unfortunately, using `-Encoding UTF8` invariably creates UTF-8 files *with* a BOM in Windows PowerShell. The solution is to use the .NET framework directly:

```
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($ATTRIBUTESFILE.FullName, $ATTRIBUTE)
```

<sup>See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34969243/45375) of mine for a convenience function that produces BOM-less UTF-8 files with syntax similar to `Out-File`.</sup>

---

<sup>[1] In PowerShell *Core*, UTF-8 without BOM is now the default encoding.</sup>

Comment: @Ayush: My pleasure; glad it helped. Re typo: oops! Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add `-Encoding UTF8` to the `Out-File`. That's probably a UTF-16 byte order mark.

Comment: Indeed, `Out-File` by default creates a UTF-16LE file (with BOM) by default (as does `>`); note that using `-Encoding UTF-8` also creates a BOM, however - can Chef handle that?

Comment: No, we assume normal file handling everywhere.

Comment: Also why would UTF-8 need a BOM?

Comment: The Unicode standard neither encourages nor discourages a UTF-8 BOM (which would more properly be called a Unicode signature). In the Unix world, most utilities neither produce a BOM when they write a UTF-8 file, nor do they know how to handle one when they read a file. Unfortunately, in the Windows world it is common to use one for the sake of backward compatibility: files without a BOM continue to be interpreted as "ANSI"-encoded. Fortunately, the cross-platform _Core_ edition of PowerShell has seen the light and now defaults to BOM-less UTF-8 too.