# Check if file is not encoded twice

Tags: powershell, character-encoding

I used the answer to this question:
[Using PowerShell to write a file in UTF-8 without the BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596982/using-powershell-to-write-a-file-in-utf-8-without-the-bom)

to encode a file(`UCS-2`) to `UTF-8`. The problem is that if I run the encoding twice(or more times) the `Cyrillic` text is broked. How to stop the encode if the file is already in `UTF-8`?

The code is:

```
$MyFile = Get-Content $MyPath
$Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($MyPath, $MyFile, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$MyFile = Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 $MyPath
```

- Initially, when `$MyPath` is UTF-16LE-encoded ("`Unicode`" encoding, which I assume is what you meant), PowerShell will *ignore* the `-Encoding` parameter due to the presence of a *BOM* in the file, which unambiguously identifies the encoding.

  - If your original file does *not* have a BOM, more work is needed.
- Once you've saved `$MyPath` as UTF-8 *without BOM*, you *must* tell Windows PowerShell<sup>[1]</sup> that you expect UTF-8 encoding with `-Encoding UTF8`, as it interprets files as "ANSI"-encoded by default (encoded according to the typically single-byte code page associated with the legacy system locale).

---

<sup>[1] Note that the [cross-platform PowerShell *Core* edition](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) defaults to BOM-less UTF-8.</sup>