# Illegal Character '?' a when I create the JSON using ConvertTo-JSON

Tags: powershell

I am not a powershell guy please excuse if my question is confusing.

We are creating a JSON file using ConverTo-JSON and it successfully creates the JSON file. However when I cat the contents of JSON it has '??' at the beginning of the json file but the same is not seen when I download the file/ view the file in file system.

Below is the powershell code which is used to create the JSON File:

```
$packageJson = @{
    packageName = "ABC.DEF.GHI"
    version = "1.1.1"
    branchName = "somebranch"
    oneOps = @{
        platform = "XYZ"
        component = "JNL"
    }
}

$packageJson | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Out-File "$packageName.json"
```

Above set of code creates the files successfully and when I view the file everything looks fine but when I cat the file it has leading '??' as shown below:

```
??{

    "packageName":  "ABC.DEF.GHI",

    "version":  "0.1.0-looper-poc0529",

    "oneOps":  {

                  "platform":  "XYZ",

                  "component":  "JNL"

               },

   "branchName":  "somebranch"

}
```

Due to this I am unable to parse JSON file and it gives out following error:

```
com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidJsonException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('?' (code 65533 / 0xfffd)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
```

Comment: Your encoding is wrong.  `Out-File` default encoding is UTF8 with BOM.  Change to `-Encoding ascii`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: Good tip re encoding, but note that `Out-File`'s default encoding is UTF-16LE ("Unicode", always with a BOM) in _Windows PowerShell_, and UTF-8 _without BOM_ in PowerShell _Core_.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 encoding by `Out-File` as ASCII is lossy. Besides, JSON [exchanged between systems](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259) is required to be encoded with UTF-8, although without a BOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those aren't `?` characters. Those are two different *unprintable* characters that make up a [Unicode byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). You see `?` because that's how the debugger, text editor, OS, or font in question renders unprintable characters.

To fix this, either change the output encoding, or use a character set on the other end that understands UTF-8. The former is [a simpler fix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-6#optional-parameters), but the latter is probably better in the long run. Eventually you'll end up with data that needs an extended character.

Comment: Good advice in general, but note that `Out-File`'s default encoding in Windows PowerShell is UTF-16LE, so that's what the other end would have to support, which is not common.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

It sounds like **your Java code expects a UTF-8-encoded file *without BOM***, so direct use of the .NET Framework is needed:

```
[IO.File]::WriteAllText("$PWD/$packageName.json", ($packageJson | ConvertTo-Json))
```

<sup>As [Tom Blodget](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2226988/tom-blodget) points out, BOM-less UTF-8 is mandated by the IETF's JSON standard, [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259).</sup>

---

Unfortunately, **Windows PowerShell's default output encoding for `Out-File` and also redirection operator `>` is UTF-16LE ("Unicode")**, in which:

- (most) characters are represented as 2-byte units.
- the file *starts* with a  special 2-byte unit (`0xff 0xfe`, the UTF-16LE encoding of [Unicode character `U+FEFF`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm) the ), the so-called (BOM byte-order mark) or Unicode signature, which serves to identify the encoding.

If target programs do not understand this encoding, they treat the BOM as *data* (and would subsequently misinterpret the actual data), which causes the problem you saw.

The specific symptom you saw - a complaint about character [`U+FFFD`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm), which is used as the generic stand-in for an *invalid* character in the input  - suggests that **your Java code likely expects *UTF-8* encoding.**

**Unfortunately, using `Out-File -Encoding utf8` is *not* a solution**, because **PowerShell *invariably* writes a *BOM*** for UTF-8 as well, [which Java doesn't expect](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-handle-utf8-file-with-bom.html).

**Workarounds:**

- If you can be sure that the JSON string contains ***only* characters in the 7-bit ASCII range** (no accented characters), you can get away with **`Out-File -Encoding Ascii`**, as [TheIncorrigible1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8188846/theincorrigible1) suggests.
- Otherwise, **use the .NET framework directly** for creating your output file with *BOM-less* UTF-8 encoding.

  - The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5596982/45375) demonstrate solutions, one of which is shown in the "tl;dr" section at the top.
- If it's an option, **use the cross-platform [PowerShell *Core* edition](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell)** instead, whose default encoding is sensibly *BOM-less UTF-8*, for compatibility with the rest of the world.

  - Note that not all Windows PowerShell functionality is available in PowerShell Core, however, and vice versa, but future development efforts will focus on PowerShell Core.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @RakeshMahendrakar; my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution that's not specific to `Out-File` is to set these before you call `ConvertTo-Json`:

```bsh
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8;
```