# How to read .xml into memory and write out the same result

Tags: xml, powershell, tivoli-work-scheduler

I am trying to read a .xml file, change some values (not yet), and write it back out. Without making any changes, I expect to get the same thing comeing out as went in. It does not.

```
PS H:\src\tws> type .\test000.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<eventRuleSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/tws/1.0/event-management/rules"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/tws/1.0/event-management/rules http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/tws/1.0/event-management/rules/EventRules.xsd">
    <eventRule name="PW-TEST001" ruleType="filter" isDraft="no">
        <description>Paul's test001</description>
    </eventRule>
</eventRuleSet>
```

Here is the simple code I am using to read it in and write it out.

```
PS H:\src\tws> Get-Content .\con000.ps1
$x = [xml](Get-Content -Path .\test000.xml)
$x | Export-Clixml -Path .\con000.xml -Encoding utf8
```

The output has  and  sections. Why is that? I would like to get out what went in. I do not care about newlines or the use of HTML entities. I just want the content to be the seme. Yes, the plan is to read a template, change some values, and output a new .xml file. This will be input to the IBM/HCS Workload Scheduler.

```
PS H:\src\tws> type .\con000.xml
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <XD>&lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;&lt;eventRuleSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/tws/1.0/event-management/rules" x
si:schemaLocation="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/tws/1.0/event-management/rules http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/tws/1.0/event-management/rules/EventRules.xsd"&gt;&lt;eventRule
name="PW-TEST001" ruleType="filter" isDraft="no"&gt;&lt;description&gt;Paul's test001&lt;/description&gt;&lt;/eventRule&gt;&lt;/eventRuleSet&gt;</XD>
</Objs>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The purpose of [`Export-CliXml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml) is to *serialize arbitrary objects* for later *deserialization* via `Import-CliXml`, using a best-effort representation with respect to preserving the specific input types for later "rehydration" via [`Import-CliXml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-clixml).
- Its purpose is *not* to write the *text representation* of arbitrary `[xml]` documents to a file.

In order to save a text representation of an [`[xml]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument) instance to a file, you have two basic choices:

- If the **specific formatting of the textual representation of the XML document is not a concern**, simply call `.OuterXml` on the (modified) `[xml]` instance and send that to a file - either via `Set-Content` or via `Out-File` / `>`, but note the different default character encodings applied by these cmdlets in Windows PowerShell.
- Use the **.NET framework**, if you want **a *pretty-printed* textual representation** of the XML in the output file:

  - The [`[xml]` type's `.Save()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.save#System_Xml_XmlDocument_Save_System_String_) conveniently performs implicit pretty-printing when saving to a file, but there are pitfalls:

    - Since .NET usually has a different idea of what the current directory is, be sure to pass a *full file path*.
    - In the absence of an XML declaration with an `encoding` attribute, the method creates a UTF-8 file *without BOM* (which is preferable from a cross-platform perspective).
    - By contrast, curiously, if an XML declaration with `encoding="UTF-8"` *is* present, the resulting file will be UTF-8 *with* a BOM, as of .NET Core 2.1 / .NET v4.7; see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/34118).
  - Use a [`[System.Xml.XmlWriter]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter) instance with an explicitly created file-stream object, which is more cumbersome but gives you control over the specifics of the pretty-printed format.

---

Here's a simple example with `.OuterXml`:

```
# Read the input file into an XML document (in-memory DOM).
$x = [xml] (Get-Content -Raw ./test000.xml)

# Make updates to the in-memory document
$x.eventRuleSet.eventRule.description = 'new description'

# Save the modified document as text to an output file,
# using the un-prettied textual representation provided by the .OuterXml
# property.
# If *BOM-less* UTF-8 encoding is what you want, simply use
#   $x.Save("$PWD/con000.xml")
# In PowerShell *Core*, you'd get BOM-less UTF-8 even with the command below.
$x.OuterXml | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 ./con000.xml
```

---

A note re the use of a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (a.k.a. Unicode signature) with [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and other Unicode encodings:

- In *Windows PowerShell*, `-Encoding utf8` *invariably* creates a BOM (applies not just to `Set-Content`, but also to other cmdlets that produce file output, such as `Out-File` and `Export-Csv`).

  - Direct use of the .NET framework is required to create BOM-*less* UTF-8 files (for a PowerShell-friendly wrapper function, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34969243/45375) of mine). Note that the .NET framework's default encoding has always been BOM-less UTF-8.
- PowerShell *Core* creates BOM-*less* UTF-8 files *by default* (and also when you explicitly use 
  `-Encoding utf8`); you can opt to have a BOM created with `-Encoding utf8BOM`.

For best overall compatibility, BOMs in UTF-8 files should be *avoided*: Unix platforms and Unix-heritage utilities also used on Windows Platforms generally don't know how to handle them.

Similarly, `-Encoding UTF7` should be avoided, because it is not a standard Unicode encoding (and is written *without* a BOM in both PowerShell editions).

In *both* PowerShell editions, all other Unicode encodings available with `-Encoding` *do* create an (encoding-appropriate) BOM: `Unicode` (UTF-16LE), `bigendianunicode` (UTF-16BE), and `utf32` (UTF-32).

Answer (score 0):

Play around with this code in the debugger.

```
$data1 = @"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<eventRuleSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/tws/1.0/event-management/rules"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/tws/1.0/event-management/rules http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/tws/1.0/event-management/rules/EventRules.xsd">
    <eventRule name="PW-TEST001" ruleType="filter" isDraft="no">
        <description>Paul's test001</description>
    </eventRule>
</eventRuleSet>
"@

$xml1 = [xml]$data1

"`n-------data1"
$data1

"`n--------xml1"
$xml1

"`n--------save to file xml2"
$xml1.Save('d:\test\xml2.xml')

$file2 = Get-Content 'd:\test\xml2.xml'
$xml2 = [xml]$file2

"`n--------file2"
$file2

"`n--------edit"
$xml2.eventRuleSet.eventRule.name = "Hello world!"

"`n--------save to file xml3"
$xml2.Save('d:\test\xml3.xml')

$file3 = Get-Content 'd:\test\xml3.xml'

"`n--------file3"
$file3
```