# Syntax error in powershell command in windows

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I try to run two commands in a bat file using the powershell. My goal is to transform a file to a utf8 format. How can I achieve that?

Here is what I have so far:

```
PowerShell -Command (Get-Content 'ZipCode.csv' | Out-File 'ZipCode1.csv' -Encoding utf8)
```

I get the following error: "out-file is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: Have you tried answer from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596982/using-powershell-to-write-a-file-in-utf-8-without-the-bom ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Actually I cannot manage to run these two commands inside the powershell in the bat file.

Comment: The PIPE is a special character. So you either quote your Powershell command to protect it or escape it with a caret if you are not going to use quotes.

Comment: Am I wrong or should it be `PowerShell -Command {Get-Content 'ZipCode.csv' | Out-File 'ZipCode1.csv' -Encoding utf8}` ... curly braces ... not parenthesis ...  ;-)

Comment: @olaf the same error..

Comment: From the help invoked with `Powershell /?` ..  `PowerShell -Command "& {...... }"`

Answer (score 2):

The doublequotes seem sufficient to escape the pipe.  Single quotes on the outside wouldn't work.

```
PowerShell "Get-Content ZipCode.csv | Out-File ZipCode1.csv -Encoding utf8"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're only using `Out-File` because your version of PowerShell doesn't include the `-Encoding` option with `Set-Content`, then it should read:

```batch-file
@"%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -Command "Get-Content -Path '.\ZipCode.csv' | Out-File -FilePath '.\ZipCode1.csv' -Encoding UTF8"
```

Obviously if you have a Version of PowerShell where `Set-Content` has the required `-Encoding` option, use it instead:

```batch-file
@"%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -Command "Get-Content -LiteralPath 'ZipCode.csv' | Set-Content -LiteralPath 'ZipCode1.csv' -Encoding UTF8"
```

---

These could obviously be shortened to remove the robustness and use aliases/shorthand:

```batch-file
@PowerShell -NoP "GC '.\ZipCode.csv'|Out-File '.\ZipCode1.csv' -E UTF8"
```

```batch-file
@PowerShell -NoP "GC -LP 'ZipCode.csv'|SC -LP 'ZipCode1.csv' -En UTF8"
```

*I prefer to use `-LiteralPath` because I have a tendency to use `[]` in my file naming, and those can be problematic in filenames. Change the output file name to `ZipCode[1]`, then try the `-Set-Content` version code with `-Path` or nothing instead of  `-LiteralPath`/`-LP` option, and you should see what I mean.*

Comment: What is `%__AppDir__%`?

Comment: Open up a Command Prompt window, enter `Echo %__AppDir__%` and take a look. It essentially always produces the path to the correct `\System32` location, _(regardless of whether you're running in `x64` or `x86` mode)_. You should always, wherever possible, use the full paths to locations without relying on registry or system variable settings, _which can be readily modified_. `%__AppDir__%` is a special dynamic variable, which cannot be overwritten, so even if you use `Set "__AppDir__=test"`, if you `Echo %__AppDir__%` it will not output `test`.

Comment: That's very strange.  It can't normally be listed through `set` in cmd, or `dir env:` in powershell.

Comment: …hence I can use it in cmd.exe without worrying about deliberate or accidental modificiation of my intended location. **Off topic:** Please note however, that because you can `Set "__AppDir__=test"`, in cmd.exe, that having done so, you can still see that it is defined using `Set __AppDir__`. You could therefore retrieve the value of  it like this `For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims==" %I In ('Set __AppDir__ 2^> NUL') Do @Echo %J`.