# Why is PowerShell typing chinese characters into my files?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make a system which turns the contents of a `.txt` file into a variable. This isn't my problem, though; for some reason, my files are reading characters I didn't enter, and can't use.

Please note: **What I'm doing is in no way efficient, and I'm positive there are other ways to go about this, but this is the best way for me.** Also, I'm not amazingly intelligent when it comes to coding. Just thought I'd throw that out there.

First, let me show you the system I have in place.

### value.txt

```
4
```

This file has the contents which I'd like to make into a variable.

## Batch Files

### setcmdvar.bat

```
set cmdvar=
```

I leave this empty so that I can put the contents of `value.txt` at the end (more on this later).

### start.bat

```
@echo off
call PowerShell.exe cd "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Folder"; $PSvar = Get-Content value.txt; $PSvar >> setcmdvar.bat
pause
call setcmdvar.bat
pause
echo The variable equals %cmdvar%.
pause
exit
```

The second line from `start.bat` creates this script in PowerShell:

## PowerShell script

```
cd "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Folder\"
$PSvar = Get-Content value.txt; $PSvar >> setcmdvar.bat
```

This creates a variable in PowerShell, `$PSvar`, which equals the contents of `value.txt`; in our case, 4. Then, it puts `$PSvar` (4) at the end of `setcmdvar.bat`, using `>>`, which changes it to:

### setcmdvar.bat (changed)

```
set cmdvar=4
```

Or, at least, it should, to my knowledge. Instead, it changes the file to this:

```
set Items=桔⁥瑳楲杮椠⁳業獳湩⁧桴⁥整浲湩瑡牯›⸢ †⬠䌠瑡来牯䥹普⁯††††㨠倠牡敳䕲牲牯›㨨 嵛‬慐敲瑮潃瑮楡獮牅潲割捥牯䕤捸灥楴湯 †⬠䘠汵祬畑污晩敩䕤牲牯摉㨠吠牥業慮潴䕲灸捥整䅤䕴摮晏瑓楲杮
```

Or some other strange combination of characters. I looked one up, and it was Chinese. There's also some other characters like †, ⬠, ›, ⸢,  , and ⁳. I have no idea why these are being typed. Along with this, start.bat displays the following:

```
Press any key to continue . . .
(PowerShell script runs here)
'■s' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Press any key to continue . . .
The variable equals .
Press any key to continue . . .
(exit)
```

I did not type "■s," and I assume this may be the problem. Whatever it is, does anyone have any ideas?

P.S. I'm sorry if my code is complicated, or if it looks bad, but I have it this way for a reason. Mostly my incompetence, actually. But I think it's better that way.

Also, I know there are commands like `for /f "delims=" %a in ('ver') do @set foobar=%a` (I just took this off the internet) but I've tried commands like those, and I suppose I just don't understand them all that well, because they didn't work.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Powershell adds a byte order marker to text by default. Batch prefers ANSI encoding. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596982/using-powershell-to-write-a-file-in-utf-8-without-the-bom

Comment: `>>` which is more correctly `Out-file -Append` can mix two encodings in the same file, even if the file was originally ASCII or ANSI. I would suggest instead that you use `Add-Content`, which should check the encoding and match that already existing when appending. BTW, the default for `Get-Content` is to use `UTF8NoBOM`, so it may also be necessary for you to use the `-Encoding` parameter, with that, probably as `ASCII`, and obviously the same parameter is available for `Add-Content` whose default is also `UTF8NoBOM` too. As a side note, `Call` is for batch files or internal labels in them!

Comment: @Compo Yes, start.bat (which includes call) is a batch file. I appreciate the help. However, I'm still getting the same issues.

Comment: `PowerShell.exe` is definitely not a batch file, @IgroSome, hence the reason I told you about `Call`!

Comment: You have really over complicated this whole process.  Either stick to doing everything in a batch file or powershell.  It makes no sense doing what you are doing.  In the simplest form to read the first line of a file in a batch file you can do this: `set /p var=<file.txt`.  If you have multiple lines you have to read then you would use a `FOR /F` command.

Comment: @Compo I know it's not a batch file, I'm not _that_ stupid.

Comment: @Squashman That's true, but I'd rather it automatically sets the variable, without user input.

Comment: If the `Call` command 'Calls one batch program from another', and `PowerShell.exe` isn't a batch program, and if you're not _that_ stupid @IgroSome, why have you used `call PowerShell.exe`?

Comment: @IgroSome, the code I gave you takes **NO** user input.  It takes the input from the file.    I thought I made that pretty clear in my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be better to avoid the static setcmdvar.bat script and write it all in the script. Using `-Encoding ascii` is what keeps the output from being Unicode and having a BOM (Byte Order Mark) at the beginning. It has nothing to do with Chinese characters.

```
ECHO>"%USERPROFILE%\value.txt" 4
SET "CMDFILE=%USERPROFILE%\setcmdvar.bat"
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "'SET ""cmdvar=' + (Get-Content $Env:USERPROFILE\value.txt) + '""""' |" ^
    "Out-File -FilePath %CMDFILE% -Encoding ascii"
pause
call "%CMDFILE%"
pause
echo The variable equals %cmdvar%
pause
EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: The ascii encoding can be limiting for certain languages. Note that the standalone versions of PowerShell (v7+ definitely, v6 I believe) have both the UTF8NoBom and UTF8BOM encodings. The former has no BOM while the latter does, if that is not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

`>>` has its problems with mixing encodings.  Plus it defaults to utf16.  I recommend changing

```
$PSvar >> setcmdvar.bat
```

to

```
add-content setcmdvar.bat $PSvar
```

I'm not sure how to keep everything on one line.  You can make setcmdvar.bat like this:

```
set cmdvar=^
```

So that it continues.