# Remove the BOM from txt file and check if removal is effective

Tags: powershell

I created a basic Powershell script that has a simple objective :

1. copy all files from a folder to another folder
2. remove BOM from those files
3. rename files

For this I created a simple script :

```
# input & ouput folders
$inputFolder  = 'C:\Users\myName\myInputFolder'
$outputFolder = 'C:\Users\myName\myOutputFolder'

# move files
Copy-item -Force -Recurse -Verbose $inputFolder\* -Destination $outputFolder

# remove bom to files
Get-ChildItem $outputFolder\*  -recurse -Include *.json,*.html,*.xml,*.js,*.txt,*.css | ForEach-Object {
   $content = $_ | Get-Content
   Set-Content -PassThru $_.Fullname $content -Encoding UTF8 -Force
}

# rename files
Get-ChildItem -Path $outputFolder\*.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '.txt','.done.txt' }
```

My question is how to check if that I correctly removed the BOM from those files.

Comment: Look at this answer, more specifically the second example: https://superuser.com/a/418520

Comment: Thanks I just found it after posting ... I note that i don't remove the BOM in this code :)

Comment: Here seems to be your answer regarding the removal of the BOM https://stackoverflow.com/a/5596984/934946 :)

Comment: Are you only talking about the UTF-8 BOM `0xEF0xBB0xBF` ? There are a lot more Byte Order Marks around like for UTF1, UTF7, UTF16-LE, UTF16-BE UTF32-LE, UTF32-BE, UFT-EBCDIC, BOCU-1, GB18030.

Comment: I just have to handle UTF8 files ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is the following :

```
foreach ($i in ls -name $inputFolder\*.txt)
{
    $file_content = Get-Content "$inputFolder\$i";
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines("$outputFolder\$i", $file_content);
}
```