# Encode File save utf8

Tags: powershell

I'm breaking my head: D
I am trying to encode a text file that will be saved in the same way as Notepad saves
It looks exactly the same but it's not the same only if I go into the file via Notepad and save again it works for me what could be the problem with encoding? Or how can I solve it? Is there an option for a command that opens Notepad and saves again?

i use now

```
(Get-Content 000014.log) | Out-FileUtf8NoBom ddppyyyyy.txt
```

and after this

```
Get-ChildItem ddppyyyyy.txt | ForEach-Object {
  # get the contents and replace line breaks by U+000A
  $contents = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($_) -replace "`r`n?", "`n"
  # create UTF-8 encoding without signature
  $utf8 = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $false
  # write the text back
  [IO.File]::WriteAllText($_, $contents, $utf8)
}
```

Comment: Which PowerShell version you are using? What is the actual problem?

Comment: The summary seems to be: there is nothing wrong with the code in the question, the true problem was embedded `NUL` characters in the files, which caused problems in `R`, and which opening and resaving in Notepad _implicitly_ removed, thereby resolving the problem (assuming that simply _discarding_ these `NUL`s works as intended).

Comment: Allow me to give you the standard advice to newcomers in the next comment; I also encourage you to revisit your previous questions.

Answer (score 1):

When you open a file with notepad.exe it autodetects the encoding (or do you open the file explicitly File->Open.. as UTF-8?). If your file is actually not UFT-8 but something else notepad could be able to work around this and converts it to the required encoding when the file is resaved. So, when you do not specify the correct input encoding in your PoSh script things are will go wrong.

But that's not all; notepad also drops erroneous characters when the file is saved to create a regular text file. For instance, your text file might contain a NULL character that only gets removed when you use notepad. If this is the case it is highly unlikely that your input file is UTF-8 encoded (unless it is broken). So, it looks like your problem is your source file is UTF16 or similar; try to find the right input encoding and rewrite it, e.g. UTF-16 to UTF-8

```
Get-Content file.foo -Encoding Unicode | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 newfile.foo
```

---

Try it like this:

```
Get-ChildItem ddppyyyyy.txt | ForEach-Object {
  # get the contents and replace Windows line breaks by U+000A
  $raw= (Get-Content -Raw $_ -Encoding UTF8) -replace "`r?`n", "`n" -replace "`0", ""
  # create UTF-8 encoding without BOM signature
  $utf8NoBom = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $false
  # write the text back
  [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($_, $raw, $utf8NoBom)
}
```

If you are struggling with the Byte-order-mark it is best to use a hex editor to check the file header manually; checking your file after I have saved it like shown above and then opening it with Notepad.exe and saving it under a new name shows no difference anymore:

[image]

The hex-dumped beginning of a file *with BOM* looks like this instead:

[image]

Also, as noted, while your regex pattern should work it want to convert Windows newlines to Unix style it is much more common and safer to make the CR optional: `r?`n

Als noted by [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) reading the file using the correct encoding is important; if your file is actually in Latin1 or something you will end up with a broken file if you carelessly convert it to UTF-8 in PoSH.
Thus, I have added the `-Encoding UTF8` param to the Get-Content Cmdlet; adjust as needed.

Comment: I can not figure out what the problem is it looks exactly the same in encoding but only after I save it again in Notepad can I use it the way I want 
It does not bring me the same saving of Notefad utf-8, The problem is I want to do this automatically I can not open the Notepad manually and save every time

Comment: I think the problem is not all the encoding when I take the original file created and open it in Notepad and save it without changing the encoding or anything I can use it what does it change in the file? How can I check?

Comment: We still don't know what's wrong with your file if you do not open it with notepad? Do you see broken characters or what is it?

Comment: I want to use to use the file in R, but if I do not open it first in Notepad and saves it I get an error in R = Error in stri_encode(txt, encoding, "UTF-8") : 
  embedded nul in string: '<U+FFFD><U+FFFD><U+FFFD>\021<U+FFFD>'
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50), If I just open it on Notepad and save without changing the encoding or anything it does work

Comment: @ranonfranranranonf aha, maybe your strings contain NULL chars. Try to filter those as well; append after the first replace: `-replace "`0", ""` Maybe it's a different control character but I am pretty sure this is the actual issue.

Comment: hi I found something that helps me read the text but is it possible to do it without destroying the order of the lines? (Get-Content ssasaas11.log -Raw)-replace '[^ -~\t]' | Set-Content dssdpppp1111OUT.txt -Force

Comment: If your file is actually UTF16 try to open it like this `Get-Content file.foo -Encoding Unicode | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 newfile.foo`

Comment: Your hex dump looks almost like binary. Is this UTF-32. Where is it from?

Comment: @wp78de, it looks like you were right about `NUL`s, though they seem to be embedded in an otherwise single-byte encoding file, judging by a comment on my answer; in that case, your `-replace "\`0"` recommendation should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

*Update*: **There is nothing wrong with the code in the question, the true problem was embedded `NUL` characters in the files**, which caused problems in `R`, and which opening and resaving in Notepad *implicitly* removed, thereby resolving the problem (assuming that simply *discarding* these `NUL`s works as intended) - see also: [wp78de's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64526690/45375).

Therefore, modifying the `$contents = ...` line as follows should fix your problem:

```
$contents = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($_) -replace "`r`n", "`n" -replace "`0"
```

---

Note: The code in the question uses the `Out-FileUtf8NoBom` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34969243/45375), which allows saving to BOM-less UTF-8 files in Windows PowerShell; it now supports a `-UseLF` switch, which would simplify the OP's command to (additional problems notwithstanding):

```
Get-Content 000014.log | Out-FileUtf8NoBom ddppyyyyy.txt -UseLF
```

---

- There's a conceptual flaw in your regex, though it is benign in this case: **instead of `` "`r`n?" `` you want `` "`r?`n" ``** (or, expressed as a pure regex, `'\r?\n'`) in order to match *both* CRLF (`` "`r`n" ``) and LF-only (`` "`n" ``) newlines.

  - Your regex would instead match CRLF and CR-only(!) newlines; however, as [wp78de](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8291949/wp78de) points out, if your input file contains only the usual CRLF newlines (and not also isolated CR characters), your replacement operation should still work.
  - In fact, you don't need a regex at all if all you need is to replace CRLF sequences with LF: `` -replace "`r`n", "`n" ``
- **Assuming that your original input files are ANSI-encoded**, you can **simplify your approach** as follows, without the need to call `Out-FileUtf8NoBom` first (**assumes *Windows PowerShell***):

```bsh
# NO need for Out-FileUtf8NoBom - process the ANSI-encoded files directly.
Get-ChildItem *SomePattern*.txt | ForEach-Object {
  # Get the contents and make sure newlines are LF-only
  # [Text.Encoding]::Default is the encoding for the active ANSI code page
  # in Windows PowerShell.
  $contents = [IO.File]::ReadAllText(
    $_.FullName, 
    [Text.Encoding]::Default
  ) -replace "`r`n", "`n"
  # Write the text back with BOM-less UTF-8 (.NET's default)
  [IO.File]::WriteAllText($_.FullName, $contents, $utf8)
}
```

Note that replacing the content of files in-place bears a risk of data loss, so it's best to create backup copies of the original files first.

---

Note: If you wanted to perform the same operation in **PowerShell [Core] v6+**, which is built on .NET Core, the code must be modified slightly, because **`[Text.Encoding]::Default` no longer reflects the active ANSI code page** and instead invariably returns a BOM-less UTF-8 encoding.

Therefore, the `$contents = ...` statement would have to change to (note that this would work in Windows PowerShell too):

```
  $contents = [IO.File]::ReadAllText(
    $_.FullName,
    [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(
      [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.AnsiCodePage
    )
  ) -replace "`r`n", "`n"
```

Comment: this the orginal file dont work Format-Hex

````
00000000   B1 98 D0 11 A9 00 01 91 A6 00 00 00 00 00 00 02  ±Ð.©..¦.......
00000010   00 00 00 00 4A 44 41 54 41 3A 68 74 74 70 73 5F  ....JDATA:https_

````
and this after notepad save work

````
00000000   B1 98 D0 11 A9 20 01 91 A6 20 20 20 20 20 20 02  ±Ð.© .¦      .
00000010   20 20 20 20 4A 44 41 54 41 3A 68 74 74 70 73 5F      JDATA:https_

``````````
but i dont know how get Same result in powershell

Comment: @ranonfranranranonf: It looks like wp78de was correct: your file contains `NUL` characters (`"\`0"`), and if it's sufficient to _remove_ them (which Notepad apparently implicitly does), simply apply another `-replace` operation: `-replace "\`0"`