# How to use here-string in PowerShell to write pip.ini and .condarc file properly?

Tags: python, powershell, encoding, pip

Disclaimer: I am getting more and more accustomed with PowerShell, but I am rather inexperienced with PowerShell.

I would like to use PowerShell together with here-string syntax to write the `pip.ini` and `.condarc` configuration files to use the Python package managers pip, conda, respectively.
With the `.condarc`, there is no error, but I think I had to rewrite it again in `Notepad++` to really make it work - I think that it is a file encoding issue:

```
mkdir 'C:\ProgramData\conda\.condarc'
echo @"
show_channel_urls: true
allow_other_channels: false
report_errors: false
remote_read_timeout_secs: 120
"@ > C:\ProgramData\conda\.condarc
```

And the following gives an error for pip.ini because of [global]:

```
mkdir 'C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini'
echo @"
[global]
index = https://xxxx/nexus/repository/xxxx/pypi
index-url = https://xxxx:8443/nexus/repository/xxxx/simple
trusted-host = xxxx:8443
"@ > C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini
```

`Get-Content pip.ini` works well, but `pip config list -v` returns:

```
PS C:\Program Files> pip config list -v
Configuration file could not be loaded.
File contains no section headers.
file: 'C:\\ProgramData\\pip\\pip.ini', line: 1
'ÿþ[\x00g\x00l\x00o\x00b\x00a\x00l\x00]\x00\n'
```

Remark: xxxx represents sensitive company information, therefore replaces real text.

I also tried to escape the square brackets with `, but without success.

Is there a way to specify some file encoding like UTF-8 above or can the problem be somehow solved in another automatized way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Windows Powershell*, the redirection operators use **`Unicode`** encoding (in other words, **[UTF-16 with the little-endian byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16)**.) That's why you see such *weird* file content. Either

- run your code from **PowerShell Core** (`pwsh.exe`), or
- use the [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) cmdlet with its `Encoding` parameter instead of `>` redirector.

However, note that *Windows PowerShell* tends to add a [UTF-8 byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) using the following code snippet:

```
$MyRawString = @"
[global]
index = https://xxxx/nexus/repository/xxxx/pypi
index-url = https://xxxx:8443/nexus/repository/xxxx/simple
trusted-host = xxxx:8443
"@
$MyPath = "C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini"
$MyRawString | Out-file -FilePath $MyPath -Encoding utf8
```

**Solution for *Windows PowerShell***. Using [.NET's `UTF8Encoding` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf8encoding.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Text_UTF8Encoding__ctor_System_Boolean_) and passing `$False` to the constructor seems to work (stolen from [this *M. Dudley*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5596984/3439404)):

```
$Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($MyPath, $MyRawString, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
```

**Explanation** `Get-Help About_Redirection`

- **Windows PowerShell** (`powershell.exe`)

> When you are writing to files, the redirection operators use **`Unicode`**
> encoding. If the file has a different encoding, the output might not
> be formatted correctly. To redirect content to non-Unicode files, use
> the [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) cmdlet with its `Encoding` parameter.

- **PowerShell Core** (`pwsh.exe`, version 6+)

> When you are writing to files, the redirection operators use
> **`UTF8NoBOM`** encoding. If the file has a different encoding, the output
> might not be formatted correctly. To write to files with a different
> encoding, use the [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) cmdlet with its `Encoding`
> parameter.

Note that there is an **error** in the [online version of the `About_Redirection` Help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-5.1#notes) for PowersShell 5.1…

Comment: That helps but no I indeed need to get rid of byte order mark and I am also not sure about the introduced "\n" at the end of global, the first line now is interpreted as 'ï»¿[global]\n'

Comment: @mgross Answer updated. `\n` is a moniker for a new line.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly: `pip --version` works now with your solution. I will accept your answer soon, but just to be correct with SO guidelines I will wait a day or too in case an even better answer would come up (I do not think so, but one never knows)

Answer (score 1):

`Out-File` Default in Windows PowerShell 5.1 is Unicode in PowerShell Core 7+ it's UTF8.

You're using `mkdir` to create a file which doesn't make sense to me.

There's no need to pre-create the file anyhow.  So, combining the above maybe something like:

```
@"
show_channel_urls: true
allow_other_channels: false
report_errors: false
remote_read_timeout_secs: 120
"@ | Out-File  C:\ProgramData\conda\.condarc

@"
[global]
index = https://xxxx/nexus/repository/xxxx/pypi
index-url = https://xxxx:8443/nexus/repository/xxxx/simple
trusted-host = xxxx:8443
"@ | Out-File C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini
```

Comment: `echo` is an alias for `Write-Output`…

Comment: @Steven Did not really resolve my issue, whereas the answer of JosefZ does. With respect to mkdir: You are right with respect to the console, but now when I integrated the commands in a PowerShell Script I seem to need it.