# How do I use PowerShell to create UTF8 file with NO BOM (Byte Order Marks)

Tags: sql-server, powershell, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I have a SQL Server SQL Agent job that is using PowerShell and the following script to create a csv file, however the script is putting hidden Byte Order Marks (BOMs) in my output. How do I remove the BOMs?

```
$query = "select * from [server].[database].[view]"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -QueryTimeout 0 -Query $query  | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Path "[FilePath\[FileName].csv"
```

I tried changing the code to:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -QueryTimeout 0 -Query $query  | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8NoBom -Path "[FilePath\[FileName].csv"
```

but received the following error:

> ...The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Encoding'. The argument "UTF8NoBOM" does not belong to the set "Unicode.UTF7.UTF8.ASCII.UTF32.BigEndianUnicode.DefaultOEM" specified by the ValidateSet attribute...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using PowerShell to write a file in UTF-8 without the BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596982/using-powershell-to-write-a-file-in-utf-8-without-the-bom)? There is also some information about Powershell and BOM in [about_Character_Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_character_encoding?view=powershell-7.4)

Comment: `-Encoding UTF8NoBOM` requires PowerShell 6.0 or later. What version of PowerShell are you launching from your SQL Agent job? i.e.: what's the output of `$PSVersionTable`?

Answer (score 0):

The [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596982/using-powershell-to-write-a-file-in-utf-8-without-the-bom) pointed to by [Xedni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1306784/xedni) has enough info to solve the problem, but in the context of CSV, it becomes a little convoluted if you want to use [Lucero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49987102/4190564).

Instead of using `Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation`, use `ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation` to first save the file's text to a variable, then use Lucero's answer to write to the file.

```
$FileText = Invoke-Sqlcmd -QueryTimeout 0 -Query $query | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
Set-Content ([Text.UTF8Encoding]::new().GetBytes($FileText)) -Encoding Byte -PSPath "[FilePath\[FileName].csv"
```