Add value with special characters to the key vault
Currently running a Powershell script in the pipeline to store the Standard Logic App Workflow URL to the Azure key vault. Running in the following issues: My script first calls en saves the result in a variable let's call it $result by using: az rest --method post --uri XXXX
(https://medium.com/@mail4ankitg/get-workflow-trigger-callback-url-in-azure-logic-app-standard-using-powershell-and-azure-cli-5cc7bf983131)
I retrieve the url by storing it in the following variable:
$urlResult = ($result | ConvertFrom-Json).value

The url usually looks something like this:

https://X.appserviceenvironment.net:443/api/NameWorkFlow/triggers/When_a_HTTP_request_is_received/invoke?api-version=2022-05-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2FWhen_a_HTTP_request_is_received%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=SIGVALUE

When I now try to add this workflow URL to the key vault:
az keyvault secret set --vault-name $keyVaultName --name "Name" --value $urlResult

My script exits with an error code:

I tried escaping the urlResult by using:
$escapedUrl = [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($urlResult)

The script runs this time but in the key vault the following value is added:

https%3A%2F%2FX.appserviceenvironment.net%3A443%2Fapi%2FNameWorkFlow%2Ftriggers%2FWhen_a_HTTP_request_is_received%2Finvoke%3Fapi-version%3D2022-05-01%26sp%3D%252Ftriggers%252FWhen_a_HTTP_request_is_received%252Frun%26sv%3D1.0%26sig%3DSIGVALUE

Lastly I also tried using the '' around the value like:
az keyvault secret set --vault-name $keyVaultName --name "Name" --value '$urlResult'

But this of course only adds "$urlResult" to the key vault.
Currently running out of options, can somebody help?
Mentioned in the post above. Tried 2 approaches but both did not result in the desired result.

Dealing with special characters can be tricky.
Try outputting the value into a text file, and then creating the secret using the --file option, instead of --value.
Something like this (not tested):
$secretFile = "$(Agent.TempDirectory)/secret.txt"

# other commands here

($result | ConvertFrom-Json).value | Out-File $secretFile -NoNewline

az keyvault secret set --vault-name $keyVaultName --name "Name" --file $secretFile --output none

# files in $(Agent.TempDirectory) are automatically deleted after the pipeline finishes,
# but better be safe than sorry
Remove-Item $secretFile -Force

EDIT 1
It might be required to specify the encoding when generating the text file - e.g. utf8 or utf8NoBOM:
($result | ConvertFrom-Json).value | Out-File $secretFile -NoNewline -Encoding utf8NoBOM

And/or setting the secret:
az keyvault secret set --vault-name $keyVaultName --name "Name" --file $secretFile --encoding utf-8 --output none


Hey thanks for the comment. I followed your advice and had to make the following adjustment since Agent.TempDirectory threw an unrecognized error in the pipeline. I'm using:
$secretFile = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($env:AGENT_TEMPDIRECTORY, "secret.txt")
and adding the secretFile as file to the key vault now. However when we try to retrieve the value we get back the following:
ÿþh\u0000t\u0000t\u0000p\u0000s\u0000:\u0000/\u0000/\u0000l\u0000a\u0000p\u0000-\u0000t\u0000-\u0000o\u0000c\u0000a\u0000r\u0000.\u0000a\u0000s\u0000e\u0000-\u0000t\u0000-\u000.......
Am I missing something?

Are you using Azure DevOps pipelines? $(Agent.TempDirectory) is a predefined variable, don't understand why it's not recognized. Don't forget to use $(myvariable) syntax.

What exactly do you mean by adding the secretFile as file to the key vault? You're using the --file option, right? Let's do one step at a time - maybe double-check if the file has the correct value?

@DJanssen added more details. Try specifying the encoding.

Hey @Rui thanks again for following up. I'm using Azure DevOps pipelines. When I used the $secretFile = "$(Agent.TempDirectory)/secret.txt" exactly how you mentioned I got the following result: https://snipboard.io/0RNxgf.jpg
I used the following command to store it in the key vault:
az keyvault secret set --vault-name $keyVaultName --name "Name" --file $secretFile --output none
That resulted in the following error in the image. Then I changed it to $secretFile = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($env:AGENT_TEMPDIRECTORY, "secret.txt") and got the u000t.. value as a result

Btw I'm using the classic pipeline editor and using the Azure CLI step to run the Powershell script after deployment of the Azure resources etc. https://snipboard.io/SQ9xrG.jpg

@DJanssen try specifying the encoding. See my edit.

Thanks for the edit, we had some issues with the pipeline so it took a while to test it out. It seems we are really close! So by following the -encoding utf8 property we see the correct url. However at the beginning we see these characters: ï»¿
So the value we retrieve from the key vault is: ï»¿
https://X.appserviceenvironment.net:443/api/workflowname/triggers/When_a_HTTP_request_is_received/invoke?api-version=2022-05-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2FWhen_a_HTTP_request_is_received%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=Sigs
If only we can get rid of these  ï»¿ characters we are good to go :) What would you suggest?

An ugly solution would be to run another command to basically cut out the first 3 characters of the secret. Not sure if that is even possible but that could work I think

@DJanssen when creating the text file try utf8NoBOM instead of utf8

this gives me the following error in the pipeline: https://snipboard.io/DSQLXT.jpg
This is how it looks like in code: https://snipboard.io/zKhasV.jpg

Which Powershell version are you using? Starting from version 6 powershell supports the UTF8NoBOM encoding

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/5596984/558486 for a workaround.

we are running version 5.1.... it seems. So need to find a way to update that to 7.0. Will try out the utf8NoBOM then thanks!

@DJanssen in the meantime try the workaround I mentioned

Hey just wanted to let you know that we managed to update the Powershell and now the value of the workflow gets saved perfectly to the key vault thanks to the NoBom encoding. Thanks a lot for your help! Cheers!

@DJanssen glad to know it's working fine. FYI you don't even need to specify the -Encoding option in the most recent versions of Powershell - its default value is utf8NoBOM.

Replace the keyvault name with your own, below script works at my side:
$value = "https://wbtest.appserviceenvironment.net:443/api/NameWorkFlow/triggers/When_a_HTTP_request_is_received/invoke?api-version=2022-05-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2FWhen_a_HTTP_request_is_received%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=sigvaluehiddenhere"

$secret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $value -AsPlainText -Force

Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'wbtestkv' -Name 'wbtestSecret2' -SecretValue $secret


Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'wbtestkv' -Name 'wbtestSecret2' -AsPlainText



Hi thanks for replying! I tested out your code but this is my result:
In the key vault the value shows: System.Security.SecureString
When my colleague calls this value in the logic app workflow by using the key vault connector the result is also System.Security.SecureString.
Am I doing something wrong?

I use the Azure CLI task to run the script, and it can work fine. The workflow URL can be set to a secret in Key Vault as expected.
Below is my sample as reference:
# azure-pipelines.yml

# Replace the variable values with your actual values.
variables:
  armConnection: 'ARM-Service-Connection-Name'
  subscriptionId: 'Azure-Subscription-Id'
  resourceGroupName: 'Resource-Group-Name'
  logicAppName: 'BriRanLA'
  workflowName: 'testWorkflow'
  keyVaultName: 'BriRanKV'
  secretName: 'workflowURL'

steps:
- checkout: none
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Set Secret'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(armConnection)'
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      $reqUri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$(subscriptionId)/resourceGroups/$(resourceGroupName)/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$(logicAppName)/hostruntime/runtime/webhooks/workflow/api/management/workflows/$(workflowName)/triggers/When_a_HTTP_request_is_received/listCallbackUrl?api-version=2018-11-01"
      $workflowDetails = az rest --method post --uri $reqUri
      $urlResult = ($workflowDetails | ConvertFrom-Json).value
      az keyvault secret set --vault-name $(keyVaultName) --name $(secretName) --value $urlResult




Interesting! Maybe it has no problems when running it as a InlineScript instead of pointing to a Path. I'll remember it for future events!

@DJanssen, Have you tried like as above sample in my answer? And whether it can work for you?
