# How to check if a .txt file is in ASCII or UTF-8 format in Windows environment?

Tags: windows

I have converted a .txt file from ASCII to UTF-8 using UltraEdit. However, I am not sure how to verify if it is in UTF-8 format in Windows environment.

Thank you!

Comment: ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so "converting" an ASCII file will do precisely nothing.

Comment: You might want to give an example of a conversion scenario - strictly speaking an ASCII file is already a UTF-8 file.  Do you mean that you want the converted file to have a byte-order-mark (BOM), or did the original file actually contain some bytes that weren't ASCII (ie., above 0x7f)?

Comment: Thanks Kerrek and Michael!  Actually, a .txt file (I think a text file is ASCII encode by default) was rejected by a vendor with the reason "The file is not UTF-8 encoded".  I did some research and found an option in UltraEdit to convert ASCII to UTF-8. So, before sending the file to the vendor, I wanted to make sure if it is UTF-8 encoded or not.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Text files in Windows don't have a format. There's an unofficial convention that if the file starts with the [BOM codepoint in UTF-8 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) that it's UTF-8, but that convention isn't universally supported. That would be the 3 byte sequence `"\xef\xbf\xbe"`, i.e. `ï¿¾` in the Latin-1 character set.

Comment: While this may be relevant, it does not answer the question of how to check. It only mentions something to check for whenever a non-universal convention might be in place, but nothing about "how to check." Suggestion to move this to a comment.

Comment: @DylanKinnett it does answer the question.  If the file starts with the byte sequence I provided, you can be 99.99% sure that it is UTF-8 encoded even if the receiver of the file can't process it properly.

Comment: @DylanKinnett the first sentence of the answer is also correct, Windows simply doesn't track the encoding of a text file on its own so there's no possible way to make it verify that encoding.

Answer (score 47):

Open the file in Notepad. Click 'Save As...'. In the 'Encoding:' combo box you will see the current file format.

Comment: Yes, I opened the file in notepad and selected the UTF-8 format and saved it.  Then, I opened the file again to see if it saved the format. This works fine for small files.  However, I cannot open large files (e.g. 200MB) in notepad. Any other ideas?  Thank you!

Comment: @rk1962 use Notepad++

Comment: This method doesn't work. I have created ANSI file then open UTF-8 file then open the ANSI file and Notepad shows UTF-8. Notepad++ works perfect though.

Comment: 1) It works for most people. You must've done something wrong. 2) Read my previous comment re Notepad++

Answer (score 13):

If you use Windows 10 and has Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), it can be easily done by typing "file " from the shell.

For example:

```
$ file code.cpp

code.cpp: C source, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Comment: If you have installed [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/), you can also do this 
 by using `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\file.exe`.

Answer (score 12):

Open the file using Notepad++ and check the "Encoding" menu, you can check the current Encoding and/or Convert to a set of encodings available.

Comment: How does this add information not included in previous answers?

Comment: @AdamMartin: This is the easiest solution presented and exactly what I was looking for. I suspect your comment was made while working the late answers review queue, no?

Comment: I have file that Notepad++ says is UTF-8 but it has no BOM; I know because I opened it using Visual Studio's binary viewer that does show BOMs when they are present.

Answer (score 8):

Open it in a hex editor and make sure that the first three bytes are a [UTF8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) (`EF BB BF`)

Comment: If the first three bytes are (EF BB BF), does it mean it is UTF-8 encoded file?  Thank you!

Comment: @rk1962: No. Those same bytes are used by pretty much any extension of ASCII, e.g. Shift-JIS (Japanese).

Comment: @MSalters is there a deleted comment that you're responding to? I thought EF BB BF at the start of a file was nearly a guarantee of UTF-8.

Comment: @MarkRansom: It's 5 years old, so I'm not 100% certain, but I think there's no missing comment. It's indeed quite likely, but that's statistical. UTF-8 is common, and many UTF-8 files start with EF BB BF. OTOH, other encodings are becoming rare, and in those encodings EF BB BF is rather rare.  No guarantees, though.

Answer (score 1):

I had a directory of files that I wanted to check.  I created an Excel macro to determine ANSI vs. UTF-8.  This worked for me.

```
        Sub GetTextFileEncoding()
        Dim sFile As String
        Dim sPath As String
        Dim sTextLine As String
        Dim iRow As Integer

        'Set Defaults and Initial Values
        iRow = 1
        sPath = "C:textfiles\"
        sFile = Dir(sPath & "*.txt")

        Do While Len(sFile) > 0
            'Get FileType
            'Debug.Print sFile & " - " & FileEncodeType(sPath & sFile)

            'Show on Excel Worksheet
            Cells(iRow, 1).Value = sFile
            Cells(iRow, 2).Value = FileEncodeType(sPath & sFile)

            'Get next file
            sFile = Dir

            'Increment Row
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Loop
    End Sub

    Function FileEncodeType(sFile As String) As String
        Dim bEF As Boolean
        Dim bBB As Boolean
        Dim bBF As Boolean

        bEF = False
        bBB = False
        bBF = False

        Open sFile For Input As #1
            If Not EOF(1) Then
                'Read first line
                Line Input #1, textline
                'Debug.Print textline
                For i = 1 To 3
                    'Debug.Print Asc(Mid(textline, i, 1)) & " - " & Mid(textline, i, 1)
                    Select Case i
                        Case 1
                            If Asc(Mid(textline, i, 1)) = 239 Then
                                bEF = True
                            End If
                        Case 2
                             If Asc(Mid(textline, i, 1)) = 187 Then
                                bBB = True
                            End If
                        Case 3
                             If Asc(Mid(textline, i, 1)) = 191 Then
                                bBF = True
                            End If
                        Case 4

                    End Select
                Next
            End If
        Close #1

        If bEF And bBB And bBF Then
            FileEncodeType = "UTF-8"
        Else
            FileEncodeType = "ANSI"
        End If
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54638926/220997), I was able to create something in PowerShell to check the first two bytes of a file (the BOM) to identify if a file is UTF-16.

It may not be completely fool-proof but it worked my situation.

```
#$folderPath = "myfolderpath\hello\"

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -File #-Recurse

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $fileContent = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file.FullName)
    $firstTwoBytes = $fileContent[0..1] | ForEach-Object { $_.ToString("X2") }

    # Write-Host "First two bytes of $($file.Name) in hexadecimal: $firstTwoBytes"
        
    if (($fileContent[0] -eq 0xFF -and $fileContent[1] -eq 0xFE) -or ($fileContent[0] -eq 0xFE -and $fileContent[1] -eq 0xFF))
    {
        #Write-Host "First two bytes of $($file.Name) in hexadecimal: $firstTwoBytes"
        Write-Host "$($file.Name) is encoded as UTF-16"
    } 
    
}
```

If you want to replace the file to UTF-8, there are some answers here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51593644/220997
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5596984/220997

Answer (score -1):

Just open notepad

in open dialog select the file and encoding will be shown for the selected file in open file dialog itself just below filename.