# File encoding format through command prompt : Windows

Tags: file, windows-7

I have a file which may be in ASCII or UTF-8 format. I can know which format it is through Notepad++. But can some one tel me a tool that could show me in which format the file is through command prompt.

**Example:** 
Open Command Prompt,

```
C:><Some Command> FileName
```

which should give me the file format like ASCII or UTF-8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a .txt file is in ASCII or UTF-8 format in Windows environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947749/how-to-check-if-a-txt-file-is-in-ascii-or-utf-8-format-in-windows-environment)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947749/how-to-check-if-a-txt-file-is-in-ascii-or-utf-8-format-in-windows-environment) which has a great answer (not by me I might add)

**EDIT**

I am pretty sure there is not way that is reliable to do this, usually you are told the encoding of a file, sure you can look for a Byte Order Mark (BOM) at the start of the file but its not mandatory and so is not a true indicator unless you know for SURE its supposed to be there.

Unless someone knows differently I don't think its possible to work out from scratch you have to have some clue about the encoding used.

Comment: I think the chcp is not for what I am looking for. Because what I was expecting is "whether there is a tool that will take a file as input and print in the file format." Example: Say we have a tool by name "TOOL." If I give in command prompt like "TOOL file.txt" then output should be either ASCII or UTF or someother format.

Comment: please clarify what you mean by print, do you mean output to the console or print on an actual printer

Answer (score -1):

1. Install Python 3.x
2. Run command in cmd.exe (Administrator): `pip install chardet`
3. Write a small python script that read a file, detect the encoding, and print the encoding using the newly installed module `chardet`. See [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) for help.
4. Put the script somewhere under `PATH`

Suppose you create `ec.py` doing the job. Then you can invoke `ec FileName` on command line to get the encoding. If you do a good job writing the python script, you can invoke something like `ec *.txt` to get the encodings of multiple files.