# Why can't the program read UTF-8 characters using Scanner?

Tags: java, file, utf-8, java.util.scanner

I initialized the **Scanner** class object in this manner:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"),"utf-8");
```

When i try to read a file with chars like ç or é, `scanner.hasNextLine()` returns false, scanner don't read nothing.

I tried to use "iso-8859-1". And file reading was successful. But file is UTF-8 file and chars like 'ç' are displayed as "Ă§".

Please help me solve the problem and make the program properly read and display UTF-8 characters.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] include the *bytes* that are in that file.

Comment: how do you know that your file is properly encoded into UTF-8?

Comment: I don't know which OS you use but try to check with this approach https://www.chainsawonatireswing.com/2012/04/22/how-can-you-tell-if-a-file-is-utf-8-encoded-or-not//?from=@

Comment: for windows try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947749/how-to-check-if-a-txt-file-is-in-ascii-or-utf-8-format-in-windows-environment

Answer (score 0):

specify encoding while writing the `UTF-8` encoded text

```
new String(scanner.next().getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
```

To get the complete line, specify delimiter in Scanner

```
scanner.useDelimiter("\n");
```

Comment: scanner.next() returns a String already why would we need to do that?

Comment: From docs `Constructs a new  String by decoding the specified array of bytes using the specified Charset.`

Comment: You convert a String into String, it doesn't make any sense. Moreover you don't do it properly because getBytes() use the default encoding so let's say that it is ISO-8858-1, it will serialize the String in ISO-8859-1, then deserialize the result in UTF-8 which cannot simply work

Comment: In the `scanner` the input encoding has given has `UTF-8` that's why while decoding I have constructed it as `UTF-8` String

Answer (score 0):

Use:

new String(scanner.next().getBytes("UTF-8"), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))