# EXCEL VBA read / write . dft file (IBM Data Tranfer)

Tags: excel, ibm-midrange, vba

I would like to edit a .dtf (IBM Data Transfer file) via VBA. Opening it in excel is causing me problems so I was hoping to read the file line-by-line and export to a new .dtf. However something goes wrong when I try to `Print #1` the string to the .dtf

[image: INPUT]

[image: OUPUT]

```
Sub test()
    Dim TemplateFilePath As String
    TemplateFilePath = "C:\TemplateFile.dtf"
    Call CreateDataTranderFile(TemplateFilePath)
End Sub



Public Sub CreateDataTranderFile(TemplateFilePath As String)
    Dim output As String
    Dim OutFullPath As String
    Dim Line As String
    Dim FileNum As Integer

    OutFullPath = "C:\tmpTranferfile.dtf"


    'Read from template
    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open TemplateFilePath For Input As #FileNum
        While Not EOF(FileNum)
            Line Input #FileNum, Line
            output = output & Line
        Wend
    Close #FileNum

    'Write .dtf
    Open OutFullPath For Output As #1
        Print #1, output
    Close
End Sub
```

Comment: With output = output & Line you skip CRLF. Is that on intention? Although I  do not believe it has anything to do with your problem.
Can you check what the encoding of your input file is?

Comment: I guess encoding of your input file is UNICODE, right?

Comment: Indeed was UNICODE. Just learned how to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947749/how-to-check-if-a-txt-file-is-in-ascii-or-utf-8-format-in-windows-environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I assume your input file is an UNICODE file then you coud use the following function

```
Function ReadUniCodeTextFile(inpFile As String) As String

Dim sText As String
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFile As Object

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(inpFile, 1, False, -1)
    ReadUniCodeTextFile = objFile.ReadAll
    objFile.Close

End Function
```

And replace

```
   'Read from template
    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open TemplateFilePath For Input As #FileNum
        While Not EOF(FileNum)
            Line Input #FileNum, Line
            output = output & Line
        Wend
    Close #FileNum
```

just with

```
output = ReadUniCodeTextFile(TemplateFilePath)
```

So your code should look like this then

```
Public Sub CreateDataTranderFile(TemplateFilePath As String)
Dim output As String
Dim OutFullPath As String
Dim Line As String
Dim FileNum As Integer

    OutFullPath = "C:\tmpTranferfile.dtf"

    'Read from template
    output = ReadUniCodeTextFile(TemplateFilePath)

    'Write .dtf
    Open OutFullPath For Output As #1
    Print #1, output
    Close
End Sub
```