# How to determine the encoding of a CSV file?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, utf-16, byte-order-mark

I'm writting script that has to make some operations on CSV file, but I have no idea if file will be encoded with utf-8 or utf-16. How to check if given csv file cointains utf-16 BOM?

Comment: Sounds like may be impossible — see [How to determine the encoding of text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/how-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text)

Comment: UTF-16 is not much used to exchange data. Try with an editor (or a browser) and check different encoding: when you see good data, it could be the correct encoding. If you see many 00 bytes, it is nearly certain a UTF-16 (or other 16 or more bits encoding). [a csv file need to have a comma, so U+002C, so in this case you have to have the 00 byte]

Comment: It might be more straightforward to tell the sender that you only accept UTF-8 (or whatever). Or accept a file format where the character encoding is not separated from the file, like .xlsx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: In general, identifying the original encoding of a text file is not a deterministic problem. If there are no metadata (eg. an HTML content-type header), you can only guess. There are tools and libraries out there that help you guessing – and some of them do a pretty good job – but you can't be 100% sure. This is especially true if 8-bit encodings (like Latin-1, Windows CP1252 etc.) are involved.

But if you already know that the encoding must be either UTF-8 or UTF-16, then you're in a good situation.

UTF-16-encoded text files must always begin with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).
You can use this fact to detect its presence.
There are two different "flavors" of UTF-16 – Big Endian (BE) and Low Endian (LE).
Since UTF-16 uses two-byte words (16 bits), there are two ways to compose them: high-byte first (BE) or low-byte first (LE).
You can tell from the BOM, ie. by looking at the very **first two bytes** of the file:

- `FE FF` → UTF-16 BE
- `FF FE` → UTF-16 LE

For UTF-8, a BOM is not strictly needed – in fact, using it is actually non-standard.
However, the fact that many Windows application have continuously refused to recognise UTF-8 encoding unless it contains a BOM led to a pseudo-standard "UTF-8 with BOM".
If the BOM is present, it occupies the **first three bytes** of the file:

- `EF BB BF` → UTF-8 with BOM

If your file starts with something different, then you either have BOM-less UTF-8, or some non-UTF encoding (ASCII, Latin-1...).